# Confused with arrays in python

Tags: python

Is this the correct way to declare and iterate through an array in Python, where each element is multiplied by a constant value?

```
timeArray = array([0]*1000)

for x in timeArray:
    timeArray[x] = x * deltaTime
    print(timeArray)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want an [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) and not the data structure that's essentially an array but is called list in Python?

Comment: I read somewhere that lists aren't good for large data structures.

Comment: If you're having *millions* of items which are equivalent to basic C data types (`int`s, `float`s, `char`, etc - see the docs), it's sometimes a useful optimization to use `array`. If that's not the case, or the code doesn't even run correctly yet (remember: "make it run, make it correct, make it fast" - optimizing is done *last*), you shouldn't even think of such optimizations. Complexity-wise, lists are just as good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
timeArray = [i*deltaTime for i in range(1000)]
```

will construct a list with the contents that you want. Indexing into a list takes O(1) time, the same as for an array. Python lists are very fast, they're actually [implemented as arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917574/how-is-pythons-list-implemented/3958322#3958322).

Are you sure you want to `print` the contents of the array/list while it's being constructed?

(Aside: If you want faster arrays because you're doing number crunching, then a Numpy array might be a better choice:

```
timeArray = numpy.arange(1000)
timeArray *= deltaTime
```

)

Comment: Won't this create a new array?

Comment: @cwallenpoole: if you were referring to my Numpy example, I just posted a version that constructs one array and modifies it in-place.

Comment: Yes it is!  Numpy is now Python 3 compatible: http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files//NumPy/1.5.0/NOTES.txt/view

Answer (score 0):

This is probably less confusing, and does what you want.

```
timeArray = [0 for i in range(1000)]

for x in timeArray:
    timeArray[x] *= deltaTime
    print(timeArray)
```

Comment: Or just `timeArray = [i*deltaTime for i in range(1000)]`

Comment: -1 This is incorrect, and rather verbose at that. It takes four lines to repeatedly set `timeArray[0] = 0`, and also prints the same 1000-element array 1000 times. @larsmans's version is great, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you really need are numpy arrays. The built-in array behaves more like lists.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from array import array

timeArray = array("f", [1]*1000)

deltaTime = 2

for i, x in enumerate(timeArray):
    timeArray[i] = timeArray[i] * deltaTime

print(timeArray)

# but numpy arrays behave more "naturally".

from numpy import array
timeArray = array([1]*1000, dtype="f")
print (timeArray * 2)
```

A numpy array will multiply all elements of the array by a scalar value.
Besides, I'm not sure that your original array code actually works. Also, numpy arrays are much faster.