# Merge 2 lists at every x position

Tags: python

Say I have two lists one longer than the other, `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and `y = [a,b,c]` and I want to merge each element in y to every 3rd index in x so the resulting list z would look like: `z = [1,2,a,3,4,b,5,6,c,7,8]`

What would be the best way of going about this in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an adapted version of the roundrobin recipe from the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) that should do what you want:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def merge(a, b, pos):
    "merge('ABCDEF', [1,2,3], 3) --> A B 1 C D 2 E F 3"
    iterables = [iter(a)]*(pos-1) + [iter(b)]
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Example:

```
>>> list(merge(xrange(1, 9), 'abc', 3))   # note that this works for any iterable!
[1, 2, 'a', 3, 4, 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7, 8]
```

Or here is how you could use `roundrobin()` as it is without any modifications:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> y = ['a','b','c']
>>> list(roundrobin(*([iter(x)]*2 + [y])))
[1, 2, 'a', 3, 4, 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7, 8]
```

Or an equivalent but slightly more readable version:

```
>>> xiter = iter(x)
>>> list(roundrobin(xiter, xiter, y))
[1, 2, 'a', 3, 4, 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7, 8]
```

Note that both of these methods work with any iterable, not just sequences.

Here is the original `roundrobin()` implementation:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
def solve(x,y):                                                             
    it = iter(y)
    for i in xrange(0, len(x), 2):
        try:
            yield x[i:i+2] + [next(it)]
        except StopIteration:    
            yield x[i:]
...

>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> y = ['a','b','c']

>>> list(chain.from_iterable(solve(x,y)))
[1, 2, 'a', 3, 4, 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

This approach modifies `x` in place.  Alternatively, you could make a copy of `x` and return the modified copy if you didn't want to change the original.

```
def merge(x, y, offset):
    for i, element in enumerate(y, 1):
        x.insert(i * offset - 1, element)

>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> y = ['a','b','c']
>>> merge(x, y, 3)
>>> x
[1, 2, 'a', 3, 4, 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7, 8]
```

All extra elements of `y` past the end of `x` just get appended to the end.

Comment: I like that this is simple and concise and I can understand it! I'm not able to comment on the performance of any of the solutions as that's above my understanding at the moment.

Comment: [Insertion is more expensive than extension or appending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776938/python-insert-vs-append).

Comment: @2rs2ts well that complicates things then! Hmm I might wait and let more experienced people vote for the best(quickest?) solution before I select an answer then

Comment: @2rs2ts Agreed, insertion is [O(n)](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).  For small data sets, my approach works but I would not advise it for large sets.

Comment: @MatthewJacobs what would you consider a large data set?

Comment: I guess that really depends on where this is used.  If it's in the middle of loop that called over and over again, you'd want just about the fastest method you could.  If, however, it's called once (perhaps occasionally) raw speed may not be tremendously important.  To put a number to it, maybe a few hundred.  However, I consider where it's used more important.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
x = range(1, 9)
y = list('abc')

from itertools import count, izip
from operator import itemgetter
from heapq import merge

print map(itemgetter(1), merge(enumerate(x), izip(count(1, 2), y)))
# [1, 2, 'a', 3, 4, 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7, 8]
```

This keeps it all lazy before building the new list, and lets `merge` naturally merge the sequences... kind of a decorate/undecorate... It does require Python 2.7 for `count` to have a `step` argument though.

So, to walk it through a bit:

```
a = list(enumerate(x))
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8)]
b = zip(count(1, 2), y)
# [(1, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (5, 'c')]
print list(merge(a, b))
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 'a'), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 'b'), (4, 5), (5, 6), (5, 'c'), (6, 7), (7, 8)]
```

Then the `itemgetter(1)` just takes the actual value removing the index...

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions are really cool. Here's an alternative that doesn't involve roundrobin or itertools.

```
def merge(x, y):
    result = []
    while y:
        for i in range(0, 2): result.append(x.pop(0))
        for i in range(0, 1): result.append(y.pop(0))
    result.extend(x)
    return result
```

where 2 and 1 are arbitrary and list y is assumed to be shorter than list x.

Comment: This is similar to my own implementation except I used one loop and a conditional. Although I suspect yours might be better performance wise

Answer (score 0):

```
sep, lst = 2, []
for i in range(len(y)+1):
    lst += x[i*sep:(i+1)*sep] + y[i:i+1]
```

Where `sep` is the number of elements of `x` before an element of `y` is inserted.

Performance:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="for i in range(len(y)+1): lst += x[i*sep:(i+1)*sep] + y[i:i+1]", setup="lst = [];x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];y = ['a','b','c'];sep = 2", number=1000000)
2.8565280437469482
```

Pretty damn good. I wasn't able to get the `stmt` to begin with `let = []` so I think it kept appending to `lst` (unless I misunderstand `timeit`), but still... pretty good for a million times.

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest, chain
>>> y = ['a','b','c']
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]   
>>> lis = (x[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0, len(x) ,2)) # generator expression
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([ (a + [b]) if b else a  
                                            for a, b in izip_longest(lis, y)]))
[1, 2, 'a', 3, 4, 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge(xs, ys):
    ys = iter(ys)
    for i, x in enumerate(xs, 1):
        yield x
        if i % 2 == 0:
            yield next(ys)

''.join(merge('12345678', 'abc')) # => '12a34b56c78'
```