# Why does adding to the front of the list take quadratic time?

Tags: python, list

This code sample takes Big O of (N^2)

```
results = []

for i in range(1000000)
    result = [f(i)] + results
```

This code sample takes Big O of (N)

```
results = []

for i in range(1000000)
    result = results + [f(i)]
```

Why is there such a distinct difference in the Big O of these two algorithms, the only difference is that one is added to the front of the list while the other is added to the back of the list?

Does this hold true for Java, also?

Comment: "Internally, a list is represented as an array; the largest costs come from growing beyond the current allocation size (because everything must move), or from inserting or deleting somewhere near the beginning (because everything after that must move)." - https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list

Comment: Both of these are O(N^2). `for i in xrange(1000000): results += [f(i)]` is O(N)

Comment: Actually, neither are O(N^2) in the current code because `result` is only ever one element long and `results` is always the empty list. Neither statement is reassigning the `results` variable.

Comment: Is the difference between `result` and `results` a typo?

Comment: [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776938/python-insert-vs-append)?

Answer (score 7):

Because lists are optimized for appending, not prepending: if you prepend, the entire list needs to be recreated.

If you want a datastructure that can append at both ends with equal efficiency, use `collections.deque`.

Comment: The list isn't recreated, all the elements are merely moved upward in memory to make room at the beginning, but it's still quadratic.

Comment: That depends, the elements can only be moved if there is actually space at the end of the array.

Comment: I like this answer, and one should infer that this applies specifically to python, but a user could be led to believe that this applies to all lists in all implementations, which isn't true. Could you note that this is specific to the python implementation?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is the case is because CPython is implemented in C and uses C arrays as the backing store for lists, and you must reallocate and move the elements before adding an element to the front of the list.

To answer the second half of your question, "Does this hold true for Java also?" The answer is yes, both primitive arrays in Java and ArrayList in Java do not allow prepending to the list without reallocating and moving the elements.

Also, your code is flawed because you are assigning to `result` and not `results`, so you aren't actually causing quadratic performance as stated in the question. A better way to demonstrate this behavior would be the following:

```
results = []
for i in range(1000000):
    results.insert(0, f(i))
```

And the append version:

```
results = []
for i in range(1000000):
    results.append(f(i))
```

Or using the `timeit` module:

```
$ python -m timeit 'results = []' 'for i in range(10000): results.insert(0, i)'
10 loops, best of 3: 50.9 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'results = []' 'for i in range(10000): results.append(i)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 794 usec per loop
```