# Is there a reason why append and insert are both there?

Tags: python, insert, append

I'm surely not the Python guru I'd like to be and I mostly learn studying/experimenting in my spare time, it is very likely I'm going to make a trivial question for experienced users... yet, I really want to understand and this is a place that helps me a lot.

Now, after the due premise, Python documentation says:

> 4.6.3. Mutable Sequence Types
>
> s.append(x) appends x to the end of the sequence (same as
>    s[len(s):len(s)] = [x])
>
> [...]
>
> s.insert(i, x) inserts x into s at the index given by i (same as
>   s[i:i] = [x])

and, moreover:

> 5.1. More on Lists
>
> list.append(x)  Add an item to the end of the list. Equivalent to
>    a[len(a):] = [x].
>
> [...]
>
> list.insert(i, x)  Insert an item at a given position. The first
>    argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so
>    a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and **a.insert(len(a),
>    x) is equivalent to a.append(x)**.

So now I'm wondering *why there are two methods to do, basically, the same thing*? Wouldn't it been possible (and simpler) to have just one `append/insert(x, i=len(this))` where the `i` would have been an optional parameter and, when not present, would have meant add to the end of the list?

Comment: `append` can insert only at the end. Its a special case of `insert`.

Comment: `append` takes constant time to run, and `insert` takes linear time to run, too; see [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) on the Python Wiki. (*Linear time*, or *O(n)*, means the time it takes to `insert` a value scales with the size of the list, while `append` is always very fast.)

Comment: It would be a simpler API to have one method but appending to a list typically has different performance characteristics compared to inserting in the middle or front, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776938/python-insert-vs-append.  You could choose to use only insert and not be bothered with append.

Comment: @thefourtheye : yes, I understand that... then why not simply make the index parameter optional with `insert` ?

Comment: @Mauris That would make a fine answer.

Comment: @danicotra Because it would likely worsen the performance, and because having two different methods is a _reminder_ that one has worse performance than the other.

Comment: @Mauris , @ nightshadequeen, @ Tris Nefzger ... ah, ok, I think I got it then, it is to make sure of the availability of a method to use when peremptory "performances-to-the-max" do make a big difference...

Comment: @Mauris : I agree with GolezTrol, wouldn't you post an answer?

Answer (score 6):

The difference between append and insert here is the same as in normal usage, and in most text editors. Append adds to *the end of the list*, while insert adds *in front of a specified index*. The reason they are different methods is both because they do different things, and because `append` can be expected to be a quick operation, while `insert` might take a while depending on the size of the list and where you're inserting, because everything after the insertion point has to be reindexed.

I'm not privy to the actual reasons `insert` and `append` were made different methods, but I would make an educated guess that it is to help remind the developer of the inherent performance difference. Rather than one `insert` method, with an optional parameter, which would normally run in linear time except when the parameter was not specified, in which case it would run in constant time (very odd), a second method which would *always* be constant time was added. This type of design decision can be seen in other places in Python, such as when methods like `list.sort` return `None`, instead of a new list, as a *reminder* that they are in-place operations, and not creating (and returning) a new list.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is great -- but another fundamental difference is that `insert` is *much slower*:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'x=list(range(100000))' 'x.append(1)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.19 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'x=list(range(100000))' 'x.insert(len(x), 1)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.514 usec per loop
```

It's *O(n)*, meaning the time it takes to `insert` at `len(x)` scales linearly with the size of your list. `append` is *O(1)*, meaning it's always very fast, no matter how big your list is.

Comment: I did try to touch on this in my answer, but this is more in depth and I like your examples. You should add this case: `python -m timeit -s 'x=list(range(100000))' 'x.insert(0, 1)'`. When I ran this I got similar results to yours, with inserting at the end being about twice as slow as append. For inserting at the beginning, which is its real worst case, it was ***160 times slower***. I realize this is a bit apples to oranges, as this isn't something append can do in-place, but it really helps to highlight where insert actually gets slow.