# How to find cumulative sum of items in a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, deque

I have a list which is like

```
a=[{'time':3},{'time':4},{'time':5}]
```

I want to get the cumulative sum of the values in reversed order like this

```
b=[{'exp':3,'cumsum':12},{'exp':4,'cumsum':9},{'exp':5,'cumsum':5}]
```

What is the most efficient way to get this ? I have read other answer where using `numpy` gives the solution like

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=numpy.cumsum(a)
```

but I need to insert the cumsum in the dictionary as well

Comment: The most efficient way is using numpy, specially if the list is very large. Whether you need the cumsum into a dictionary depends on your application, and it might just come from bad *design*. Why don't you use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)? It seems to suit perfectly with your example.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo, Thanks. My lists are not large but of varying lengths. The number of such list is a million

Comment: Uset [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) or [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#the-python-profilers) to evaluate the solutions.  Let us know the results.  For solutions that convert the list to another object type, be sure to include that conversion in the timing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a=[{'time':3},{'time':4},{'time':5}]
b = []
cumsum = 0
for e in a[::-1]:
    cumsum += e['time']
    b.insert(0, {'exp':e['time'], 'cumsum':cumsum})
print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'exp': 3, 'cumsum': 12}, {'exp': 4, 'cumsum': 9}, {'exp': 5, 'cumsum': 5}]
```

---

So it turns out that inserting at the start of a list is [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776938/python-insert-vs-append) (O(n)). Instead, try a `deque` (O(1)):

```
from collections import deque


a=[{'time':3},{'time':4},{'time':5}]
b = deque()
cumsum = 0
for e in a[::-1]:
    cumsum += e['time']
    b.appendleft({'exp':e['time'], 'cumsum':cumsum})
print(b)
print(list(b))
```

**Output:**

```
deque([{'cumsum': 12, 'exp': 3}, {'cumsum': 9, 'exp': 4}, {'cumsum': 5, 'exp': 5}])
[{'cumsum': 12, 'exp': 3}, {'cumsum': 9, 'exp': 4}, {'cumsum': 5, 'exp': 5}]
```

---

Here is a script to test the speed of each of the approaches ITT, as well as a chart with timing results:

[image]

```
from collections import deque
from copy import deepcopy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import randint
from time import time


def Nehal_pandas(l):
    df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    df['cumsum'] = df.ix[::-1, 'time'].cumsum()[::-1]
    df.columns = ['exp', 'cumsum']
    return df.to_json(orient='records')


def Merlin_pandas(l):
    df           = pd.DataFrame(l).rename(columns={'time':'exp'})
    df["cumsum"] = df['exp'][::-1].cumsum()
    return df.to_dict(orient='records')


def RahulKP_numpy(l):
    cumsum_list = np.cumsum([i['time'] for i in l][::-1])[::-1]
    for i,j in zip(l,cumsum_list):
        i.update({'cumsum':j})


def Divakar_pandas(l):
    df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    df.columns = ['exp']
    df['cumsum'] = (df[::-1].cumsum())[::-1]
    return df.T.to_dict().values()


def cb_insert_0(l):
    b = []
    cumsum = 0
    for e in l[::-1]:
        cumsum += e['time']
        b.insert(0, {'exp':e['time'], 'cumsum':cumsum})
    return b


def cb_deque(l):
    b = deque()
    cumsum = 0
    for e in l[::-1]:
        cumsum += e['time']
        b.appendleft({'exp':e['time'], 'cumsum':cumsum})
    b = list(b)
    return b


def cb_deque_noconvert(l):
    b = deque()
    cumsum = 0
    for e in l[::-1]:
        cumsum += e['time']
        b.appendleft({'exp':e['time'], 'cumsum':cumsum})
    return b


def hpaulj_gen(l, var='value'):
    cum=0
    for i in l:
        j=i[var]
        cum += j
        yield {var:j, 'sum':cum}


def hpaulj_inplace(l, var='time'):
    cum = 0
    for i in l:
        cum += i[var]
        i['sum'] = cum


def test(number_of_lists, min_list_length, max_list_length):
    test_lists = []

    for _ in range(number_of_lists):
        test_list = []
        number_of_dicts = randint(min_list_length,max_list_length)
        for __ in range(number_of_dicts):
            random_value = randint(0,50)
            test_list.append({'time':random_value})
        test_lists.append(test_list)

    lists = deepcopy(test_lists)
    start_time = time()
    for l in lists:
        res = list(hpaulj_gen(l[::-1], 'time'))[::-1]
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('hpaulj generator:'.ljust(25), '%.2f' % (number_of_lists / elapsed_time), 'lists per second')

    lists = deepcopy(test_lists)
    start_time = time()
    for l in lists:
        hpaulj_inplace(l[::-1])
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('hpaulj in place:'.ljust(25), '%.2f' % (number_of_lists / elapsed_time), 'lists per second')

    lists = deepcopy(test_lists)
    start_time = time()
    for l in lists:
        res = cb_insert_0(l)
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('craig insert list at 0:'.ljust(25), '%.2f' % (number_of_lists / elapsed_time), 'lists per second')

    lists = deepcopy(test_lists)
    start_time = time()
    for l in lists:
        res = cb_deque(l)
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('craig deque:'.ljust(25), '%.2f' % (number_of_lists / elapsed_time), 'lists per second')

    lists = deepcopy(test_lists)
    start_time = time()
    for l in lists:
        res = cb_deque_noconvert(l)
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('craig deque no convert:'.ljust(25), '%.2f' % (number_of_lists / elapsed_time), 'lists per second')

    lists = deepcopy(test_lists)
    start_time = time()
    for l in lists:
        RahulKP_numpy(l) # l changed in place
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('Rahul K P numpy:'.ljust(25), '%.2f' % (number_of_lists / elapsed_time), 'lists per second')

    lists = deepcopy(test_lists)
    start_time = time()
    for l in lists:
        res = Divakar_pandas(l)
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('Divakar pandas:'.ljust(25), '%.2f' % (number_of_lists / elapsed_time), 'lists per second')

    lists = deepcopy(test_lists)
    start_time = time()
    for l in lists:
        res = Nehal_pandas(l)
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('Nehal pandas:'.ljust(25), '%.2f' % (number_of_lists / elapsed_time), 'lists per second')

    lists = deepcopy(test_lists)
    start_time = time()
    for l in lists:
        res = Merlin_pandas(l)
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('Merlin pandas:'.ljust(25), '%.2f' % (number_of_lists / elapsed_time), 'lists per second')
```

Comment: Thanks @craig, But is this the reasonably  efficient way ?. Because I have about a million lists like this

Comment: Time the various approaches here and let us know :)

Answer (score 2):

A generator based solution:

```
def foo(a, var='value'):
    cum=0
    for i in a:
        j=i[var]
        cum += j
        yield {var:j, 'sum':cum}

In [79]: a=[{'time':i} for i in range(5)]
In [80]: list(foo(a[::-1], var='time'))[::-1]
Out[80]: 
[{'sum': 10, 'time': 0},
 {'sum': 10, 'time': 1},
 {'sum': 9, 'time': 2},
 {'sum': 7, 'time': 3},
 {'sum': 4, 'time': 4}]
```

In quick time tests this is competitive with `cb_insert_0`

The in-place version does even better:

```
def foo2(a, var='time'):
    cum = 0
    for i in a:
        cum += i[var]
        i['sum'] = cum
foo2(a[::-1])
```

Comment: Plus for the *in-place* version.

Comment: adding to timings :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
cumsum_list = np.cumsum([i['time'] for i in a][::-1])[::-1]
for i,j in zip(a,cumsum_list):
     i.update({'cumsum':j})
```

**Result**

```
[{'cumsum': 12, 'time': 3}, {'cumsum': 9, 'time': 4}, {'cumsum': 5, 'time': 5}]
```

**Efficiency**

Change into a function,

```
In [49]: def convert_dict(a):
....:     cumsum_list = np.cumsum([i['time'] for i in a][::-1])[::-1]
....:     for i,j in zip(a,cumsum_list):
....:              i.update({'cumsum':j})
....:     return a
```

And then the result,

```
In [51]: convert_dict(a)
Out[51]: [{'cumsum': 12, 'time': 3}, {'cumsum': 9, 'time': 4}, {'cumsum': 5, 'time': 5}]
```

Finally efficiency,

```
In [52]: %timeit convert_dict(a)
The slowest run took 12.84 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.1 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using `pandas` -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.columns = ['exp']
df['cumsum'] = (df[::-1].cumsum())[::-1]
out = df.T.to_dict().values()
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [396]: a
Out[396]: [{'time': 3}, {'time': 4}, {'time': 5}]

In [397]: out
Out[397]: [{'cumsum': 12, 'exp': 3}, {'cumsum': 9, 'exp': 4}, {'cumsum': 5, 'exp': 5}
```

Comment: How fast is pandas in converting dict to df and back?  That must take a lot more time than the cumsum.

Comment: @hpaulj No idea really! Would be nice to some timings I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a            = [{'time':3},{'time':4},{'time':5}]
df           = pd.DataFrame(a).rename(columns={'time':'exp'})
df["cumsum"] = df['exp'][::-1].cumsum()
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Dicts are not ordered.

```
 [{'cumsum': 12, 'exp': 3}, {'cumsum': 9, 'exp': 4}, {'cumsum': 5, 'exp': 5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas`:

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame([{'time':3},{'time':4},{'time':5}])

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   time
0     3
1     4
2     5

In [6]: df['cumsum'] = df.ix[::-1, 'time'].cumsum()[::-1]

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   time  cumsum
0     3      12
1     4       9
2     5       5

In [8]: df.columns = ['exp', 'cumsum']

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
   exp  cumsum
0    3      12
1    4       9
2    5       5

In [10]: df.to_json(orient='records')
Out[10]: '[{"exp":3,"cumsum":12},{"exp":4,"cumsum":9},{"exp":5,"cumsum":5}]'
```