# Why/how is CPython reverse() so fast? Does CPython's reverse() re-point the pointers in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, reverse, cpython

Suppose I want to write a function that reverses the words in a sentence without using the `split` function. Here is one possible solution:

```
def reverse_words_1(s):
    i, n, r = 0, len(s), []
    while i < n:
        while i < n and s[i] == ' ': i += 1
        if i == n: break
        p = i 
        while i < n and s[i] != ' ': i += 1
        # Instead of appending here and then reversing after the while
        # loop is done, we could r.insert(0, ..). But insert is much
        # slower than append/reverse because insert always requires that
        # each pointer in the list must be copied and moved. Whereas
        # append only requires copying if there isn't enough space for
        # the new element in the currently allocated memory block.
        # Helpful explanations:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776938/python-insert-vs-append
        # https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/34036-timing-difference-insert-vs-append-reverse
        r.append( s[p : i] )
    r.reverse()
    return ' '.join(r)
```

The comment in my code notes that `insert` is much slower than `append/reverse`. But my comment really only compares the actions taken by `insert` and `append`. My comment doesn't address the actions or speed of `reverse`.

So how does `reverse` work in CPython? My guess is that `reverse` is re-pointing the pointers in the list. Something like this:

```
def reverse(lst):
    l, r = 0, len(lst) - 1
    while l < r:
        lst[l], lst[r] = lst[r], lst[l]
        l += 1
        r -= 1
```

Is this roughly how CPython internally performs the `reverse` function?

If my guess about how `reverse` works is correct, then I guess it's much faster to re-point pointers than it is to copy and move pointers?

Comment: You could always [look](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2486).

Comment: Thank you for the link @chepner. It's still somewhat challenging for me to find functions in the CPython codebase.

Comment: because you are comparing an because using `.insert(0, x)` makes the algorithm quadratic time instead of linear.

Answer (score 1):

That's more or less how it works the code is in [listobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c).  The code below reverses a slice but the reverse method calls this using the whole list.

```
/* Reverse a slice of a list in place, from lo up to (exclusive) hi. */
static void
reverse_slice(PyObject **lo, PyObject **hi)
{
    assert(lo && hi);

    --hi;
    while (lo < hi) {
        PyObject *t = *lo;
        *lo = *hi;
        *hi = t;
        ++lo;
        --hi;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So I guess it's a lot faster to re-point pointers than it is to copy and move pointers? If so, why?

Comment: Every time you insert an entry at the front of a list all of the pointers in the list have to be moved. As the list gets bigger insert will get progressively slower.  Append will only require the pointers to be copied if the lists internal buffer is full and it needs to be resized.

Comment: Is it much faster to re-point pointers than it is to copy and move pointers? I should have put more emphasis that this is my key question.

Comment: The pointer swapping used in the reverse function is much faster because the complexity of the function is O(N / 2), while the complexity of moving the pointers is O(N^2).  So for a list of 10,000 elements the reverse function only has to iterate over 5000 elements, while the move and insert has to loop over (1 + 2 + 3 + ... 10000) = 50005000 elements.  The difference gets progressively larger as the lists get longer.

Comment: Thank you again. Why is the complexity of moving pointers O(N^2)?

Comment: I am not talking about the complexity of moving a pointer I am just talking about the naive implementation of loop that would move the pointers for each insertion.