# Underlying datastructure of list, tuple, dict

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary, set, tuples

I would like to get some understanding on how the data types in python - list, tuple, dict and set - are implemented

How are they implemented, importantly the data structure used.
Any place/ url to *precisely* get this understanding?

Comment: [Source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/) would be my first preference.

Comment: Implemented in Python, Jython, PyPy, ... ?

Comment: The underlying implementations are _implementation details_ and you cannot assume they will be the same across all Python implementations.

Comment: I am sorry about the ambiguity
I am interested to know about the reference implementation CPython.

However does it differ with the other implementations?

I am interested to know the datastructure rather than the native data type used in the implementations. For eg: is 'dict' implemented using a hash map. why. this kind of information.

Thank you

Comment: I'd agree with @thefourtheye. The CPython source is delightfully well-commented: check `dictobject.c`, `listobject.c`, `setobject.c` and `tupleobject.c` at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2e8a142dbccc/Objects

Comment: Voting down on this seems harsh.

Comment: [How is Python's List Implemented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917574/how-is-pythons-list-implemented)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best place to look is the [`CPython` implementation source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/):

- [`dict`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/dictobject.c) - Hash map targeting fast resolution of keys
- [`list`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c) - Looks like an array of `PyObject`s
- [`tuple`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/tupleobject.c) - Same as list but with optimisations that a tuple can allow (fixed size, objects)
- [`set`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/setobject.c) - Hash map with optimisations for cache locality

The source code is heavily commented and well written `C`. This would be the best place to understand the data structures used in detail.

Comment: thank you!
I tried searching for something like this and did not get a good result. Thank you.