# Regarding python lists

Tags: python, list

We see a lot of operations on lists using its index like L[index] and we get the value associated with that index in a particular list.

I have a doubt on what exactly is python doing when we say "get me an element at this particular index(L[index])".

Is L[index] like a pointer which points to a particular value in the list and is it the reason why the value is changed through the assignment L[index]=value in the same address unlike other variables?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is L[index] like a pointer which points to a particular value in the list ...

No. It is an indicator to the compiler that the `__getitem__()`, `__setitem__()`, or `__delitem__()` method (or their C-level equivalents) of the object should be called depending on which operation is required.

Comment: These methods can be called directly. One would call the ability to use `[ ]` syntactic sugar.

Comment: Sure, but it's syntactic sugar in C/etc. as well, equivalent to `(L + index)`.

Comment: Then how come is L[index] O(1) complexity?

Comment: @Bhanusri: `del L[index]` is **not** O(1).

Comment: is getting a value at a particular index (value=L[index]) O(1)?

Comment: For lists, yes.

Comment: can you please explain how?

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation yet?

Comment: implementation of the list?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I was just adding some extra info for OP, not correcting you :)

Comment: @2rs2ts: I understand, I was just adding a little bit to the conversation as well.

Comment: @Bhanusri Recommend  [how is python list implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917574/how-is-pythons-list-implemented) for more information