# Meaning of list[-1] in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a piece of code here that is supposed to return the least common element in a list of elements, ordered by commonality:

```
def getSingle(arr):
    from collections import Counter
    c = Counter(arr)

    return c.most_common()[-1]  # return the least common one -> (key,amounts) tuple

arr1 = [5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3]

counter = getSingle(arr1)

print (counter[0])
```

My question is in the significance of the -1 in `return c.most_common()[-1]`. Changing this value to any other breaks the code as the least common element is no longer returned. So, what does the -1 mean in this context?

Comment: When I run this i get `4`, which is the correct answer.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: `[-1]` means the last element in a sequence, which in this is case is the list of  tuples like `(element, count)`, order by count descending so the last element is the least common element in the original collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: See [How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta] -- or, similarly, [How to deal with questions of the type "I don't understand how this code works?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797/how-to-deal-with-questions-of-the-type-i-dont-understand-how-this-code-works); in general, such questions are too broad to be on-topic here. By contrast, "*what does foo[-1] mean in Python?*" would specific enough to be on-topic here, but also a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One of the neat features of Python lists is that you can index from the end of the list. You can do this by passing a negative number to `[]`. It essentially treats `len(array)` as the 0th index. So, if you wanted the last element in `array`, you would call `array[-1]`.

All your `return c.most_common()[-1]` statement does is call `c.most_common` and return the last value in the resulting list, which would give you the least common item in that list. Essentially, this line is equivalent to:

```
temp = c.most_common()
return temp[len(temp) - 1]
```

Comment: Python has lists though, not arrays

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The concepts are similar (although the implementation is not that of an array but of a linked list) so I tend to use the term interchangeably.

Comment: Python does have (dynamically sized) arrays and calls them "list", they are not linked lists.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Are they not? My misunderstanding then. I suppose that they interpret down to C-style arrays that get resized based on some algorithm, then?

Comment: Correct, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917574/how-is-pythons-list-implemented