# Is python list values saved in consecutive memory locations like arrays?

Tags: python

In arrays the values of arrays stored in consecutive memory locations, ao I have to ask that is python list values saved in consecutive memory locations like arrays?

Comment: How the list is stored in memory is an implementation detail that you can't rely on.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917574/how-is-pythons-list-implemented

Comment: The list stores pointers to values elsewhere in memory.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks but these pointers are consecutive or not (I have to ask this actually)...

Comment: Discussions that I've seen say that the pointer buffer is contiguous.  When it runs out of growth room it copies those pointers to a new larger buffer.  But that's an implementation detail.  Your use of 'consecutive' might mean something different.

Comment: If you're looking for contiguous storage, have a look at [numpy.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

Comment: Right.  It doesn't matter, because you can't access the memory anyway.  A list contains a set of object references.  If you have a list of numbers, the NUMBERS are not stored consecutively.  You might have a set of object pointers stored consecutively, and each object contains one integer.  When you say "I have to ask", the real response is, "no, you don't".

Answer (score 0):

In Cpython, Yes. It is consecutive.

That is also why when list operations that involve memmove or copy past almost whole list can be time-consuming and should be avoided.

For example, if you use

```py
a = list(...)
a.pop(n) # n is not -1 or last index
```

It actually means this in C

```c
if ((size_after_pop - index) > 0) {
    memmove(&items[index], &items[index+1], (size_after_pop - index) * sizeof(PyObject *));
}
status = list_resize(self, size_after_pop);
```

Answer (score -3):

Python lists are actually arrays i have checked it

```
a = [i for i in range(10)]
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(id(a[i]) , end=' ')

# [0, 1, 2]
# 140586625908944 140586625908976 140586625909008
```

you can see that all addresses are contiguous.
the gap is 32 which is size of integer that is dedicated.

Comment: This is an implementation detail in CPython and can't be relied on.