# How to insert elements between elements for multiple Python lists?

Tags: python, list, insert

Let's say I have multiple Python lists. What is one fast way to insert elements between the elements of the multiple Python lists?

```
# Have
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [10, 11, 12]
list3 = [20, 21, 22]

# Expect
list_between = [1, 10, 20, 2, 11, 21, 3, 12, 22]
```

Answer (score 6):

```py
list_between = [i for l in list(zip(list1, list2, list3)) for i in l]
```

Just use zip and print the elements in order within the list of tuples using list comprehension.

```
list(zip(list1, list2, list3)) # returns [(1, 10, 20), (2, 11, 21), (3, 12, 22)]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pure python solution for arbitrary insertion

If you want to insert elements from `listB` into an arbitrary position in `listA`, there's the `list.insert(index, object_to_insert)` method.

If you're very concerned with speed, you should know that this probably won't be very fast because python lists are [implemented as dynamic arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917574/how-is-pythons-list-implemented), not linked lists. For faster insertion, you may want to implement your own linked list type.

## Alternate numpy solution

If you want to combine three lists in exactly the way shown by your example, you can insert them into a `numpy` array and take the transpose of the array.

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: listA = [1, 2, 3]
   ...: listB = [4, 5, 6]
   ...: listC = [7, 8, 9]
   ...:
   ...: arr = np.array([listA, listB, listC])
   ...: arr.T
Out[2]:
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])

In [3]: arr.T.flatten()
Out[3]: array([1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9])

In [4]: arr.T.flatten().tolist()
Out[4]: [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks @Emerson Harkin very helpful didn't know you could do that. How do you combine the transposed matrix then?

Comment: Happy to help @YiXiangChong! I added more details to the numpy solution to show how to turn it into a list.

Comment: Wow @Emerson Harkin this is a very brilliant solution. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Would ```np.transpose``` work for large datasets or matrices? I'm not exactly sure how numpy transpose works but theoratically it should be quite expensive to transpose for large matrices..?

Answer (score 2):

There is `roundrobin` in [itertools.recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), which do what you want:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [10, 11, 12]
list3 = [20, 21, 22]

list_between = list(roundrobin(list1,list2,list3))
print(list_between)
```

Output:

```
[1, 10, 20, 2, 11, 21, 3, 12, 22]
```

Note that it also works for arguments of varying length (see docstring).

Comment: Hi @Daweo thanks for sharing. I am new to programming so quite hard for me to understand do you mind explaining the code?

Comment: @YiXiangChong: I fear that I am unable to do so clearly, I suggest looking for python iterators tutorials and then itertools module documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```py
import itertools

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(list1, list2, list3)))
```

If the lists do not have the same length, all lists will be shrinked to the length of the shortest one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any simple/fast ways, but if the example is representative where you want to essentially build up lists from multiple lists in this manner you could just do:

```
n = 3 # length of our lists, must all be the same for simple logic
our_lists = [list1, list2, list3]
new_list = []
for i in range(3):
    for l in our_lists:
        new_list.append(l[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

If all lists have the same number of elements you can use zip in a list comprehension:

```
list_between = [ e for e3 in zip(list1,list2,list3) for e in e3 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky way but slower compared to using `np.transpose`. This is achieved by inserting `0`'s in between the elements using `slice` and then adding the lists together:

```
# e.g.
# arr1 = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
# arr2 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0]
# arr3 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3]
#
# arr_ = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3] # use np.add to fast insert
 
list1 = np.insert(list1, slice(1, None, 1), 0) # create 0,0 paddings in between
list1 = np.insert(list1, slice(1, None, 2), 0)
list1 = np.insert(list1, 0, [0]*(0))
list1 = list1.tolist()
list1.extend([0]*(3-1))

list2 = np.insert(list2, slice(1, None, 1), 0)
list2 = np.insert(list2, slice(1, None, 2), 0)
list2 = np.insert(list2, 0, [0]*(0+1))
list2 = list2.tolist()
list2.extend([0]*(3-2))

list3 = np.insert(list3, slice(1, None, 1), 0)
list3 = np.insert(list3, slice(1, None, 2), 0)
list3 = np.insert(list3, 0, [0]*(0+2))
list3 = list3.tolist()
list3.extend([0]*(3-3))

list_ = np.add(list1, list2)
list_ = np.add(list_, list3)

list_
array([ 1, 10, 20,  2, 11, 21,  3, 12, 22])
```

Comment: Note: This only works for numbers. Feedback much appreciated