# Are the memory references to 2D list elements in python contiguous?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

Python implements list with references in memory  (i.e., pointers if you might say) to its actual elements. These references are contiguous in memory.
Example:

```
# RefX, RefY and RefZ are contiguous memory references to the following elements
list_example = [elementX, elementY, elementZ] 

#insert elementS at (index 1) will shift all the next references (RefY and RefZ in this 
 case) in the memory (assume each ref is  8 bit size)

list_example = [elementX, elementS, elementY, elementZ]

#Therefore insert operation time complexity is O(N)
```

My question is:

In case of 2D list: If I append an element to the end of the first list:

```
list_of_lists[0].append(item)
```

would this case result in shifting the references of elements in second and third list in memory?

**My main point: I am asking because I am wondering if implementing list of three stacks (as a list of lists) is costly operation in terms of time complexity in case of append or pop?**

Comment: "These references are contiguous in memory." no they aren't

Comment: `list_of_lists[0][1].append(item)` means it's 3-dimensional, since `list_of_lists[0][1]` has to be a list.

Comment: Did you mean `list_of_lists[0].append(item)`?

Comment: Even if a list is contiguous, each list is independent. They don't even know that they're referenced by `list_of_lists`.

Comment: It's like an array of pointers in C. Calling `realloc()` on one of the pointers doesn't reallocate any of the other pointers.

Comment: @Barmar..yeah sorry you are right

Comment: Contagious maybe

Comment: @MaherBouidani I think roganjosh's point is that there's nothing in the language that requires them to be contiguous, it's an implementation detail.

Comment: my main point guys, am I safe to assume that append or pop in the first stack is O(1)  or it is O(n) because it shifts all next references?

Comment: @roganjosh, they are contiguous man. look at this plz : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917574/how-is-pythons-list-implemented

Comment: @MaherBouidani - in cpython an append may realloc the list depending on its current size. A pop shifts all references after the pop point down. Its not O(1).

Comment: @tdelaney, I think man pop() is O(1) because you are poping out the last element. Now in case you pop from within the list(i.e., pass item --> pop(item)), It is O(N)

Comment: @MaherBouidani - I was thinking of "pop" generally. Popping from the end shrinks the list if the used slots fall below half of the total allocated slots.