# Why do Python list sizes in memory not match documentation?

Tags: python, memory

I've been trying to gain a better understanding of how Python allocates memory for lists when the list is being extended by appending.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204377/memory-size-of-list-python) covers the basics well and explains the memory increments increase in size as the length of the list increases.  This [article](https://www.opensourceforu.com/2021/05/memory-management-in-lists-and-tuples/) is an explaination of the source code that can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c).

I want to ask about this explanation:

> ```
> /* This over-allocates proportional to the list size, making room
>  * for additional growth.  The over-allocation is mild, but is
>  * enough to give linear-time amortized behavior over a long
>  * sequence of appends() in the presence of a poorly-performing
>  * system realloc().
>  * Add padding to make the allocated size multiple of 4.
>  * The growth pattern is:  0, 4, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 52, 64, 76, ...
>  * Note: new_allocated won't overflow because the largest possible value
>  *       is PY_SSIZE_T_MAX * (9 / 8) + 6 which always fits in a size_t.
>  */
> new_allocated = ((size_t)newsize + (newsize >> 3) + 6) & ~(size_t)3;
> /* Do not overallocate if the new size is closer to overallocated size
>  * than to the old size.
>  */
> ```

And specifically, this calculation:

> new_allocated = ((size_t)newsize + (newsize >> 3) + 6) & ~(size_t)3;

My understanding of this calculation is the new memory allocation will be equal to the newsize (the current size triggering the increase) + the newsize right rolled three bits (an effective divide by eight) + 6.  This is then ANDed with the 1's complement of 3 so the last two bits are forced to zero to make the value divisible by 4.

I used this code to generate my lists and report the sizes:

```
a = [i for i in range(108)]
print(sys.getsizeof(a))  # 920 bytes

b = [i for i in range(109)]
print(sys.getsizeof(b))  # 1080 bytes
```

At 109 elements the resize is triggered an newsize now equals 928 bytes

The calculation above should look like this:
[image: Binary calculation]

1048 bytes is less than the reported size of 1060 bytes.

The documentation states that this process may not work well with small lists so I tried a bigger list.  I won't reproduce this in binary.

```
a = [i for i in range(10640)]
print(sys.getsizeof(a))  # 85176 bytes

b = [i for i in range(10641)]
print(sys.getsizeof(b))  # 95864 bytes
```

> [85184 + (86184 >> 3) + 6] = 95838 bytes

This will drop to 95836 when the "& ~3" is applied.  Again, short of the 95864 reported.

Why is the reported resize greater then the calculated resize?

Comment: Why don't you try triggering a resize by using `append` or the likes? Two list comprehensions aren't really a great comparision (Plus there probably is more code related to the list comprehension that's not in the file you are looking at).

Comment: I did.  That's how I found the crossover points.  The code provided is just shorter than "for i in range(1000): a.append(i)" but it gives the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your mistake is that you do this computation on bytes. You have to do it on elements instead and then add the overhead of an empty list object.

Here is a quick simulation of `[i for i in range(109)]`:

```py
size = 0
used = 0
for _ in range(109):
    used += 1
    if used > size:
        size = (used + ((used >> 3) + 6)) & ~3

print(f"allocated array size: {size * 8}")
print(f"full list size: {size * 8 + sys.getsizeof([])}")
print(f"should be the same as {sys.getsizeof([i for i in range(109)])}")
```

> allocated array size: 1024
>
> full list size: 1080
>
> should be the same as 1080

The factor of 8 is `sizeof(void*)` in C and would be 4 on a 32 bit system.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you.  This problem comes originally from this YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwxjMKBMR7s) comparing prime sieves and looking at the memory overheads.  I suspect the comparison of array sizes may be off.  Now I have a way of investigating.  Thank you.