# Python - Make an Array: n by n

Tags: python, arrays, size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to define Two-dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

I have a variable that represents the number files in a file, n. I want to make a array whose size is 'n' x 'n'. Then I want to fill it with just 0's. Is an array the same as a list of lists? How do you make an array in Python, and how do you make it 'n' by 'b' big? This is probably a very novice question, but I'm new to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Hi Naveen, welcome to StackOverflow! The next question is: Why do you need to create a (presumably uninitialized) 2D list beforehand at all? You don't usually have to do this in Python but create the list as you go along. A bit more info on what you're actually trying to do would be useful (you can edit your own post and add more information).

Comment: To the downvoters: This is not a question that warrants downvotes in my opinion. It's a perfectly legitimate question for a Python novice. +1 from me just for that.

Comment: Again: Please, explain your downvotes. People likes to learn something when asking SO. In the case of newcomers posts this should be an obliged policy imho

Comment: @Tim I'm guessing they're due to this being a duplicate question. Since part of the downvote help text is "does not show any research effort" that could be considered an appropriate use.

Comment: Oh ok sorry I'll keep that in mind next time I post a question.