# Python 2.7 creating a multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

In Python I want an intuitive way to create a 3 dimensional list.

I want an (n by n) list.  So for n = 4 it should be:

```
x = [[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]]]
```

I've tried using:

```
y = [n*[n*[]]]    
y = [[[]]* n for i in range(n)]
```

Which both appear to be creating copies of a reference.
I've also tried naive application of the list builder with little success:

```
y = [[[]* n for i in range(n)]* n for i in range(n)]
y = [[[]* n for i in range(1)]* n for i in range(n)]
```

I've also tried building up the array iteratively using loops, with no success.  I also tried this:

```
y = []
for i in range(0,n):
    y.append([[]*n for i in range(n)])
```

Is there an easier or more intuitive way of doing this?

Comment: Using numpy for multidimensionally arrays/lists could save you a ton of headache.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think your list comprehension versions were very close to working. You don't need to do any list multiplication (which doesn't work with empty lists anyway). Here's a working version:

```
>>> y = [[[] for i in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
>>> print y
[[[], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []]]
```

Answer (score 6):

looks like the most easiest way is as follows:

```
def create_empty_array_of_shape(shape):
    if shape: return [create_empty_array_of_shape(shape[1:]) for i in xrange(shape[0])]
```

it's work for me

Answer (score 4):

A very simple and elegant  way is:

```
a = [([0] * 5) for i in range(5)]
a
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Neat.  Extends to multiple dimensions like: `a = [[[([0]*2) for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)]`

Answer (score 3):

i found this:

```
Matrix = [[0 for x in xrange(5)] for x in xrange(5)]
```

You can now add items to the list:

```
Matrix[0][0] = 1
Matrix[4][0] = 5

print Matrix[0][0] # prints 1
print Matrix[4][0] # prints 5
```

from here: [How to define two-dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Comment: That was mine, from before your edits. I've removed it now, since your answer is at least sensible now. I think it's still technically wrong, since the questioner specifically wanted an `n` by `n` by `0` three dimensional structure and you're only making an `n` by `n` two dimensional one.

Comment: fair enough. but this answer can be easily extended to 3D, no? or maybe i misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 3):

In Python I made a little factory method to create a list of variable dimensions and variable sizes on each of those dimensions:

```
def create_n_dimensional_matrix(self, n):
  dimensions = len(n)
  if (dimensions == 1): 
    return [0 for i in range(n[0])]

  if (dimensions == 2): 
    return [[0 for i in range(n[0])] for j in range(n[1])]

  if (dimensions == 3): 
    return [[[0 for i in range(n[0])] for j in range(n[1])] for k in range(n[2])]

  if (dimensions == 4): 
    return [[[[0 for i in range(n[0])] for j in range(n[1])] for k in range(n[2])] for l in range(n[3])]
```

run it like this:

```
print(str(k.create_n_dimensional_matrix([2,3])))
print(str(k.create_n_dimensional_matrix([3,2])))
print(str(k.create_n_dimensional_matrix([1,2,3])))
print(str(k.create_n_dimensional_matrix([3,2,1])))
print(str(k.create_n_dimensional_matrix([2,3,4,5])))
print(str(k.create_n_dimensional_matrix([5,4,3,2])))
```

Which prints:

1. The two dimensional lists   (2x3), (3x2)
2. The three dimensional lists (1x2x3),(3x2x1)
3. The four dimensional lists (2x3x4x5),(5x4x3x2)

   ```
   [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]

   [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

   [[[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]]]

   [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]

   [[[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]], [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]], [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]], [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]], [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]]

   [[[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]], [[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]]
   ```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
class MultiDimList(object):
    def __init__(self, shape):
        self.shape = shape
        self.L = self._createMultiDimList(shape)
    def get(self, ind):
        if(len(ind) != len(self.shape)): raise IndexError()
        return self._get(self.L, ind)
    def set(self, ind, val):
        if(len(ind) != len(self.shape)): raise IndexError()
        return self._set(self.L, ind, val)
    def _get(self, L, ind):
        return self._get(L[ind[0]], ind[1:]) if len(ind) > 1 else L[ind[0]]
    def _set(self, L, ind, val):
        if(len(ind) > 1): 
            self._set(L[ind[0]], ind[1:], val) 
        else: 
            L[ind[0]] = val
    def _createMultiDimList(self, shape):
        return [self._createMultiDimList(shape[1:]) if len(shape) > 1 else None for _ in range(shape[0])]
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.L)
```

You can then use it as follows

```
L = MultiDimList((3,4,5)) # creates a 3x4x5 list
L.set((0,0,0), 1)
L.get((0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import copy
dimensions = 2, 3, 4
z = 0
genList = lambda size,value: [copy.deepcopy(value) for i in range(size)]
for i in dimensions: z = genList(i, z)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am amazed no one tried to devise a generic way to do it.
See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33460217/5256940

```
import copy

def ndlist(init, *args):  # python 2 doesn't have kwarg after *args
    dp = init
    for x in reversed(args):
        dp = [copy.deepcopy(dp) for _ in xrange(x)] # Python 2 xrange
    return dp

l = ndlist(0, 1, 2, 3, 4) # 4 dimensional list initialized with 0's
l[0][1][2][3] = 1
```

Edit: Built on user2114402's answer: added default value parameter

```
def ndlist(s, v):
    return [ndlist(s[1:], v) for i in xrange(s[0])] if s else v
```

Comment: I'm not sure if SO should handle cross-links smarter :)

Comment: Possibly. I've deleted my comment anyway since it no longer applies... :)

Comment: See user2114402's answer. That's a generic way post more than 2 years before your's. "I am amazed that no one" reads previously posted answers ;-).

Comment: whoops...missed that :D. I originally posted the answer for the other question and I copied that here. Upvoted user2114402's for the short recursive answer.

Comment: I am interested in an even more generic answer to that question. Imagine we have N dimensions and we need to both get and set an element. Getting an element will be a relatively simple recursion, while setting an element is not that easy (correct me if I am wrong). "l[1][1][1]" won't work simply because we don't know the number of dimensions in advance.

Comment: I don't quite get exactly what you want. You assumed that the list is an N (known) dimensional list and said you can't set the element in the list because N is unknown?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that will give you an N dimensional "matrix" filled up with copies of a copiable object.

**Edit**: This is a slight modification of pterodragon's original answer, which I much prefer to user2114402's less readable answer. In fact, outside of a doc-string the only difference from pterodragon's solution is that I explicitly use a list of dimension sizes, rather than have the user pass them as arguments.

```
import copy

    def instantiate_mdl(dim_maxes, base=0):
        """ Instantiate multi-dimensional list, that is a list of list of list ...

        Arguments:
            dim_maxes (list[int]): a list of dimension sizes, for example 
            [2, 4] represents a matrix (represented by lists) of 2 rows and 
            4 columns.     

            base (object): an optional argument indicating the object copies
            of which will reside at the lowest level in the datastructure.
        Returns:
            base (list[base]): a multi-dimensional list of lists structure,
            which is filled with clones of the base parameter.
        """
        for dim_max in reversed(dim_maxes):
            base = [copy.deepcopy(base) for i in range(dim_max)]
        return base

data = instantiate_mdl([3, 5])
data[0][0] = 99999
data[1][1] = 88888
data[2][4] = 77777

for r in data:
    print(r)

>>> # Output
>>> [99999, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> [0, 88888, 0, 0, 0]
>>> [0, 0, 0, 0, 77777]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a losution that works for any number of dimention :

```
def multi_dimensional_list(dimensions, filling=None):
    if len(dimensions) == 1:
        return [filling] * dimensions[0]
    else:
        return [
            multi_dimensional_list(dimensions[1:], filling)
            for _ in range(dimensions[0])
        ]


print(multi_dimensional_list([2, 3, 4], 0))
"""
    output :
    [
        [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
        [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
    ]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic way of doing it.

```
def ndlist(shape, dtype=list):
    t = '%s for v%d in xrange(shape[%d])'
    cmd = [t % ('%s', i + 1, i) for i in xrange(len(shape))]
    cmd[-1] = cmd[-1] % str(dtype())
    for i in range(len(cmd) - 1)[::-1]:
        cmd[i] = cmd[i] % ('[' + cmd[i + 1]  + ']')
    return eval('[' + cmd[0] + ']')

list_4d = ndlist((2, 3, 4))
list_3d_int = ndlist((2, 3, 4), dtype=int)

print list_4d
print list_3d_int
```

Result:

```
[[[[], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []]], [[[], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []]]]
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also build a 2D list with different length rows using the append method.
e.g.

```
sf_gcov_cell = []
sf_gcov_cell.append(['r1_c1', 'r2_c2_', 'r3_c3__', 'r4_c4'])
sf_gcov_cell.append(['r2_c1', 'r2_c2'])
sf_gcov_cell.append(['r3_c1', 'r3_c2___', 'r3_c3_'])
print(sf_gcov_cell)
```

Result:

```
[['r1_c1', 'r2_c2_', 'r3_c3__', 'r4_c4'], ['r2_c1', 'r2_c2'], ['r3_c1', 'r3_c2___', 'r3_c3_']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple recursive function that continuously appends new arrays to the initialized arrays within itself.

```py
#  Counts the maximum amount of dimensions in an array
def dcounter(array: list, total = 1):

    for arr in array:
        return dcounter(arr, total + 1)

    return total


#  Create array with specified amount of dimensions
def nd_array(dimensions = 1, array = list(), i = 0):

    if dimensions > 1:
        array.append([])
        nd_array(dimensions - 1, array[i])
        
    return array


#  Create a 5D array
array = nd_array(5)
print(array) #  =>  "[[[[[]]]]]"


#  Get the maximum amount of dimensions in the array
amount = dcounter(array)
print(amount) #  =>  "5"
```

If you wanted to specify the size of each dimension, the amount of arrays within each dimension, then you could modify `nd_array` into doing so.