# Python - how to inspect / discover list has references?

Tags: python, list, reference

One of the more confusing aspects in python is instantiating a list of lists (assuming one isn't using numpy) - for instance, if one tries to do it via simpler multiplication you end up with reference copies:

```
In [1]: a = [[0] * 4] * 4
In [2]: a
Out[2]: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

In [3]: a[0][1] = 1
In [4]: a
Out[4]: [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

As mentioned in various other SO post such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447882/python-2-7-creating-a-multidimensional-list), a proper way to instantiate without any references would be as follows:

```
In [5]: b = [[0 for i in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
In [6]: b         
Out[6]: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

In [7]: b[0][1] = 1
In [8]: b                                           
Out[8]: [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The question is this - assume one does define their list as done with list `a`, is there a way to inspect the array in such a way that it will show that it is using references? Merely printing the array will not reveal the references.

Comment: References are used in both cases. For CPython there is `sys.getrefcount()` which may indicate how many references point to an object

Comment: All objects in python have an address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some terminology first: you are talking about lists here (not arrays), which always store references to their elements.

A quick way to check whether all references in a list refer to different objects is

```
>>> l1 = [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
>>> l2 = [[0, 1]]*2
>>> 
>>> len(set(map(id, l1))) == len(l1) # no duplicates
True
>>> len(set(map(id, l2))) == len(l2) # duplicates
False
```

which simply checks whether there are `n` unique ids for the objects in a list of length `n`.

If your list has a very large number of elements, it might be more efficient to do this lazily and return `False` on the first duplicate id.

```
def all_unique(lst):
    seen = set()
    for x in lst:
        id_ = id(x)
        if id_ in seen:
            return False
        seen.add(id_)
    return True
```

... works like this:

```
>>> all_unique(l1)
True
>>> all_unique(l2)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `id` function:

```
>>> a = [[0] * 4] * 4
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> [id(sublist) for sublist in a]
[1975671202696, 1975671202696, 1975671202696, 1975671202696]
>>> b = [[0 for i in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
>>> b
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> [id(sublist) for sublist in b]
[1975671204808, 1975671205128, 1975671205000, 1975671204872]
```

As you can see, in `a`, the ids are all the same, while in `b`, they are different.