# Declaring and populating 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to declare and populate  a 2d array in python as follow:

```
def randomNo():
    rn = randint(0, 4)
    return rn

def populateStatus():
    status = []
    status.append([])
    for x in range (0,4):
        for y in range (0,4):
            status[x].append(randomNo())
```

But I always get IndexError: list index out of range exception. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define Two-dimensional array in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time when you add 'rows' to the status array is before the outer for loop.
So - `status[0]` exists but `status[1]` does not.
you need to move `status.append([])` to be inside the outer for loop and then it will create a new 'row' before you try to populate it.

Answer (score 7):

More "modern python" way of doing things.

```
[[ randint(0,4) for x in range(0,4)] for y in range(0,4)]
```

Its simply a pair of nested list comprehensions.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't increase the number of rows in `status` for every value of `x`

```
for x in range(0,4):
    status.append([])
    for y in range(0,4):
        status[x].append(randomNo())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're question is about generating an *array of random integers*, the numpy module can be useful:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.randint(0,4, size=(4,4))
```

This yields directly

```
array([[3, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 0, 3, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 2]])
```