# Double array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, double

I have two "matrix" `[X] = [X1,X2,...,Xn]` and `[T](Xi) = [Ti1,Ti2,...,Tim]` with `Xi` and `Tij` are reals numbers. `Xi` describe the position of point X (one dimensional), `[T](Xi)` describe the velocity of `Xi`.

I want to create a double array A in Python so: `A=A[Xi][Tj]`.

By example:

```
A[0][i] = [T](X1) = T1j = [T11,T12,...,T1m]
```

and

```
A[1][i] = [T](X2) = T2j = [T21,T22,...,T2m]
```

I tried:

```
tableA = [X,T]
```

but that does not work well.

Comment: Ca you add a short example of your expected inputs and desired output? Preferably as executable Python code. i.e. `X = [0, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Could you add the dimensions of X, T and A? I suppose that X is (nx1) that A is (nx?), but I don't get the dimension of T.

Comment: Do you have a list of T for each point in X? Then it looks like you just need a dict(). Are m,n fixed? An alternative would be a list of lists.

Comment: By example X=[0,2,4,6,8] (so X is matrix 1x5)
T(X=0) = [1,2,3,4]
T(X=2) = [1,2,3,4]
...
So A=[X][T], A(X=0)[0] = T(X=0)[0] = 1

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, because I'm not sure I fully understood your question - but the gist I'm getting is you essentially want a two dimensional array in Python?  Then this question will help:

[How to define two-dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Comment: Please post this sort of thing as a comment, not an answer.  In fact, if you believe that the question is a duplicate of the one you've linked to, please feel free to flag it as a duplicate, which will direct future visitors to the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite hard to understand, but I take it you want a matrix A, where the rows of A correspond to the T vectors?

That, you can create like this:

```
x_vector = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, ...]
a_matrix = [t_matrix(X[i]) for i in range(len(X))]
```

Then, you'll see that

```
>>> a_matrix[0][:]
[t11, t12, t13, ..., t1m]
>>> a_matrix[1][:]
[t21, t22, t23, ..., t2m]
```

if `t_matrix` is a matrix where the `xi`'th row is the velocity vector for `xi`. Now `a_matrix` will be a matrix where the `i`th row is the velocity vector for `xi`.