# How to convert matrix to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a matrix into a pandas data frame:

```
matrixA={}
matrixA[0,0]='a'
matrixA[0,1]='b'
matrixA[1,0]='c'
matrixA[1,1]='d'
```

Like this:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(matrixA)
```

I get an error.

Comment: you are creating a DICT, not a "matrix"

read: 
10 Minutes to pandas

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As already said your are not creating a matrix but a python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). However a dict can serve as parameter to create a dataframe, but you reversed the indexing order.

```
import pandas as pd

matrixA={}
matrixA['a']=[0,0]
matrixA['b']=[0,1]

pd.DataFrame(matrixA)

   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  1
```

Additionally you can use [numpys](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) matrix

```
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
pd.DataFrame(a)

   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

Comment: I used this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

"If all you want is a two dimensional container to hold some elements, you could conveniently use a dictionary instead:

'Matrix = {}'

Then you can do:

'Matrix[1,2] = 15'
'print Matrix[1,2]'

This works because 1,2 is a tuple, and you're using it as a key to index the dictionary. The result is similar to a dumb sparse matrix."

So now I would like to save the data I saved that way in DataFrame
It is feasible to use a build in function?

Comment: Well the answer you refer to, is a bit out of the context of what you are trying to do. Pandas DataFrame init can't handle a dictionary like that (as the error you should recieve indicates) and besides that I don't think it is a really pythonic way to use a dict like that.

Comment: Thanks greole for the help! I will try to run away from this way of using "dict" next time. Now i will pass my values of this "dict" using 2 loops to the DataFrame. Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Well, I was wondering if we could use python's multi-dimensional array. Yes, you can use python matrix (as mentioned in the python official docs) or multi-dimensional arrays and convert into pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
matrix = [
    ["a", 1],
    ["b", 2]
]
pd.DataFrame(matrix)

   0  1
0  a  1
1  b  2
```