# Adding rows to an empty 2D NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to start with an empty 2D  NumPy array, and then add some rows to it. However, so far I have only been able to do this with a 1D array. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
a = numpy.array([])
a = numpy.append(a, [1, 2])
a = numpy.append(a, [8, 8])
print a
```

The output I get is:

```
[1, 2, 8, 8]
```

Whereas I want the output to be:

```
[[1, 2], [8, 8]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
>>> a = numpy.empty((0,2),int)
>>> a = numpy.append(a, [[1, 2]], axis=0)
>>> a = numpy.append(a, [[8, 8]], axis=0)
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 8,  8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.vstack(([1, 2], [8, 8]))
array([[1, 2],
       [8, 8]])
```

Comment: `numpy.array(([1, 2], [8, 8]))` would do the same. The question is how to append rows to an initially empty array and your code doesn't address that.

Comment: Both `vstack` and `append` end up using `concatenate`.  They just differ in how they tweak the inputs before.