# Matrix basic help in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix

```
n=input("r")
m=input("c")
l=range(m*n)
for r in range(m):
    for c in range(n):
        l[r][c]=input(" enter no")
for r in range(m):
    for c in range(n):
        print[r][c]
    print
```

i thought of practicing matrix questions but when i ran my matrix coding in python it gave an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/WORK/Python 2.7/matrix1", line 6, in <module>
    l[r][c]=input(" enter no")
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

i m new and a student please help explain simply please i really need to understand it

Comment: `l=range(m*n)` doesn't create a "matrix", just a list of integers, so `l[r]` is an `int` and you can't index into it with `c`.

Comment: `range(.)` will give you a 1 dimensional array, you try to access it as a 2D array. Example: `>>> range(5)` --> `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: so how shold i edit the coding

Comment: How to make a 2D array a.k.a. matrix, use Google and you will find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n=input("r")
m=input("c")
myMatrix = [[0 for col in xrange(m)] for row in xrange(n)]
for row in xrange(n):
    for col in xrange(m):
        myMatrix[row][col] = input("enter no: ")
```

Now, to look at the matrix:

```
for row in myMatrix:
    for num in row:
        print num,
    print ""
```

Your problem comes from the fact that `range(m*n)` returns a flat list, when what you want is a list of sublists (where each sublist is a row in the matrix)

Answer (score 0):

To create a 2D matrix replace:

```
l=range(m*n)
```

by:

```
l=[[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> n=4
>>> m=3
>>> l=[[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]  # you can use any value instead of 0 to initialize matrix
>>> l
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For create matrix I advise you to use [numpy](https://numpy.org/)

An example here [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-c5f4ceae0ab4b1313de41aba9104d0d7648e35cc)

With `l=range(m*n)` you create a list, not a 2D matrix.