# Algorithm for filling a matrix

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, matrix

I need some help for solving this problem. I need to write a function that fills seats in a theater.
For example we have this theater:

```
theater = [ [1, 1, 1, 0], # 1 row

            [1, 0, 1, 0], # 2 row

            [0, 0, 0, 0], # 3 row
          ]
```

We have to fill the seats from the beginning of the row.
 
First, we have to fill the row with least filled seats.
If we have 2 rows with equal number of filled seats we fill the one with lower row number (we have to fill row 2 if it has the same number of filled seats as row 3).
Finally, we have to fill till all the seats are filled.
Empty seats are 0 and filled ones - 1.
The result has to be list of tuples - first element will be row's number and the second one - column's number - (2,1) - row #2 and column #1 for example.

Example:

```
theater = [ [1, 1, 1],
           [1, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 0] ]

expected = [(4, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Show your code here. Any particular issue you are facing in your code?

Comment: I don't know where to start from? I'm learning Python for about a month and this problem is a bit difficult for me. Any ideas?

Comment: I really don't know what to do. Please, help me.

Comment: Hay @croorc , check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No one is going to tell you very preliminary things.

I can send you along the correct lines though. Look up how to define 2 dimensional arrays. Create 2 variables for rows and columns. Start rows and columns from 0,0. Keep increasing columns until it is equal to max seats in a row, set it to zero and increment row.

How to define two-dimensional array in python[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6667288/1891327)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is :

- firstly you identify empty seat in theater
- then reverse empty list
- then filtering empty list check upper row empty seat length are equal with
- current row empty seat are same position with upper row empty seat position then add it in temporary list and repeat it for next upper row
- then you get your final result

By this procedure this code:

```
theater = [ [1, 1, 1],
           [1, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 0] ]

empty = [[(i+1 ,j+1) for j in range(len(theater[i])) if theater[i][j] == 0]  for i in range(len(theater)) ]
empty = empty[::-1]
#print empty

final_result = []
for i in range(len(empty)):
    result = []
    if i != len(empty)-1 and empty[i] not in final_result:
        j = i+1
        while len(empty[i]) == len(empty[j]):
            flag = False
            for first, second in zip(empty[i], empty[j]):
                if first[1] != second[1]:
                    flag = True
                    break
            if flag:
                break
            else:
                result.insert(0, empty[j])
                j = j+1
                if j == len(empty):
                    break


        for rr in result:
            final_result.append(rr)
        final_result.append(empty[i])

    if empty[i] not in final_result:
        final_result.append(reversed(empty[i]))


expected = []
for i in final_result:
    expected.extend(i)

print expected
```

Output:

```
[(4, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```