# Python 2d array iteration

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have two lists, one with a parameter name and one with a pin name, and I am trying to combine the two lists into a 2d matrix but I cannot get the syntax right.

For example:

```
list1 = [parm1,parm2,parm3]
list2 = [end1,end2,end3]
```

and I want the matrix to be:

```
matrix1= [[parm1+ end1,parm1+end2, parm1+end3]
          [parm2+ end1,parm2+end2, parm2+end3]
          [parm3+ end1,parm3+end2, parm3+end3]
```

right now my code is

```
for i in range(len(parm_name)):
    for j in range(len(end_name)):
        pin_name[i][j] = parm_name[i] + end_name[j]
```

and it's not working.

Comment: What error are you getting? See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6667201/3465172

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reassigning elements of a preinitialized `list`, simply create a new one:

```
list1 = [parm1,parm2,parm3]
list2 = [end1,end2,end3]
matrix1 = [[p+e for e in list2] for p in list1]
```

That last line can be expanded into the following equivalent code:

```
matrix1 = []
for p in list1:
    result = []
    for e in list2:
        result.append(p+e)
    matrix1.append(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `matrix1` with the following:

```
matrix1 = [[p_name + e_name for e_name in list2] for p_name in list1]
```

You don't give much code so it's difficult to say why yours isn't working.  I suspect that you don't initialize your matrix appropriately.  But you don't need to initialize then assign, you can do it all in one step with list comprehension