# Arrays in models - how is it done?

Tags: python, arrays, django-models, model

I've read the documentation on models in Django and I don't see a clear way to implement what I'm hoping to do.  I'd like to make a model where one of the fields is a 2 dimensional array.  Something like this:

```
class DesignMatrix(models.Model):
    Matrix_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Matrix_Description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
    Matrix = a 2-dimensional array of float values
```

Guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe, it can help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python

Comment: Thanks.  This improved my understanding on matrices in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done if you are using PostgreSQL. Django recently added support for ArrayField.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

If that is not an option, consider serializing your 2D array to a text or binary field.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: I think I'll be going down the PostgreSQL route.  I was hoping to not have to switch DB's, but in the end this is what needs to be done.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: since you're using Django's ORM it shouldn't be too painful of a transition

Comment: Actually I'm having some issues with the transition to postgress.  I'm posting it as a separate questions however.