# Numpy array of dicts

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, multidimensional-array

In Python, I have a dict has pertinent information

```
arrowCell = {'up': False, 'left': False, 'right': False}
```

How do I make an array with i rows and j columns of these dicts?

Comment: List out the expected output array?

Comment: what do you mean? Basically I want an ndarray of i rows and y columns of these dicts, I'll access them by index to change the False values to True as needed

Comment: Right, so how must the ndarray look like for the sample `arrowCell ` listed in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to make a two dimensional i & j is explained really well on the site already 
at this: 
[How to define two-dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python) link.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Although your problem isn't clear but if you want keys and values of dictionary in form of ndarray you can try this:

```
l = {'up': False, 'left': False, 'right': False}
a = []
for key, value in l.iteritems():
    temp = [key,value]
    a.append(temp)
```

result of that will be :

```
>>> a
[['right', False], ['up', False], ['left', False]]
```

or you can just try l.items(), result of which will be :

```
>>> l.items()
[('right', False), ('up', False), ('left', False)]
```

hope that helps and link given above gives you best way to define two dimensional array.