# How to define one matrix or two-dimensional array with different column value type and retrieve the column efficiently in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

According to this post [How to define two-dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)
,

we can create one two-dimensional array var

```
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(5)]
```

or

`numpy.zeros((5, 5))`

It seems the type of value in this matrix is same. **Am I right?**

Now, I want one matrix like

```
matrix = 
[[ 0, ['you', 'are', 'here']],
 [ 1, ['you', 'are', 'here']],
 ...
]
```

Also can get the result of the `column 0` is `[0, 1, ...]`, and `column 1` is `[['you', 'are', 'here'], ['you', 'are', 'here']]`.

**Is that possible in Python? If so, how to implement it efficiently?**

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.repeat` and `array.T` method :

```
>>> np.array((np.arange(N),np.repeat([test],N,axis=0)),dtype=object).T
array([[0, array(['you', 'are', 'here'], 
      dtype='|S4')],
       [1, array(['you', 'are', 'here'], 
      dtype='|S4')],
       [2, array(['you', 'are', 'here'], 
      dtype='|S4')],
       [3, array(['you', 'are', 'here'], 
      dtype='|S4')],
       [4, array(['you', 'are', 'here'], 
      dtype='|S4')],
       [5, array(['you', 'are', 'here'], 
      dtype='|S4')],
       [6, array(['you', 'are', 'here'], 
      dtype='|S4')],
       [7, array(['you', 'are', 'here'], 
      dtype='|S4')],
       [8, array(['you', 'are', 'here'], 
      dtype='|S4')],
       [9, array(['you', 'are', 'here'], 
      dtype='|S4')]], dtype=object)
>>>
```

Or in python use `itertools.repreat` and `zip` :

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> N=10
>>> test=['you', 'are', 'here']
>>> 
>>> np.array(zip(range(N),repeat(test,N)),dtype=object)
array([[0, ['you', 'are', 'here']],
       [1, ['you', 'are', 'here']],
       [2, ['you', 'are', 'here']],
       [3, ['you', 'are', 'here']],
       [4, ['you', 'are', 'here']],
       [5, ['you', 'are', 'here']],
       [6, ['you', 'are', 'here']],
       [7, ['you', 'are', 'here']],
       [8, ['you', 'are', 'here']],
       [9, ['you', 'are', 'here']]], dtype=object)
```