# list indices wrong type

Tags: python, runtime-error

This is the code I'm trying to run

```
import random
def createBoard(rows, columns, mines):
    board = [["C" for row in range(rows)],[" " for col in range(columns)]]
    for i in range(0, mines):
        board[[int(random.randrange(rows))],[int(random.randrange(columns))]] = "C", "*"
    return board
createBoard(9, 12, 10)
board = board
print(board)
```

This is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\Python\createBoard.py", line 7, in <module>
    createBoard(9, 12, 10)
  File "C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\Python\createBoard.py", line 5, in createBoard
    board[[int(random.randrange(rows))],[int(random.randrange(columns))]] = "C", "*"
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: `board[[int(random.randrange(rows))],int(random.randrange(columns))]]`, create a tuple here. There is two lists in it(one is `[int(random.randrange(rows))]`, another one is `[int(random.randrange(columns))]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [How to define two-dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python) for a detailed discussion on two dimensional arrays in Python.

Basically, two dimensional arrays in python don't work as board[x, y], they are actually arrays of arrays as in board[x][y].

You'll want to refactor your code such that

```
for i in range(0, mines):
        board[[int(random.randrange(rows))],[int(random.randrange(columns))]] = "C", "*"
```

looks more like

```
for i in range(0, mines): 
    boardfor i in range(0, mines):
    board[int(random.randrange(rows))][int(random.randrange(columns))]] = "C", "*"
```

Hope this was helpful!