# Creating an array matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

i'm trying to create an 2-dimensional matrix with an array, but i don't quit understand it yet.

I've tried this

```
for i in range(x):
for k in range(y):
array.array('u', [i] : [k])
```

I'm trying to make an field with x, y as in height and width.

edit:

well, i've changed it now and came to this solution, wich fixs my problem

```
import array


x = int(input('width: '))
y = int(input('height: '))

Matrix = array.array("u", ['.' for i in range(x) for k in range(y)])
Matrix.tounicode
print(Matrix)
```

With this i'm creating an field as an array, although i have to see how tounicode really works, possible i need a hash-function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define two-dimensional array in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

This I believe is your answer. I don't know how to mark as a duplicate.

[How to define two-dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Comment: But is it an array, or arraylist? Because i want it to have constant runtime. Thats what i dont quit get it yet, it seems i always get arraylist, and not an array.

Comment: In the case I have linked to it would more resemble a dictionary in the likes of java. But you can look at it as a case of an array inside of an array. e.g.  var array = [[0,0], [0,1]];