# How to index into nested lists?

Tags: python

I want to make a function in python which receives as arguments a matrix, a coordinate for the line and another coordinate for the column. For example: A matrix `m=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` and the function will receive the arguments `(m,0,0)`
It should return 1 (Which is the number located in position 0,0 in the matrix).

Comment: 1. This is a nested list, not a matrix. 2. To access the first element of the first element: `m[0][0]`.

Comment: Indeed, sorry. What i meant to say is that that list represents a matrix.

Comment: well, what about the trouble coding this task? What is the specific issue?

Comment: I really can't do What I'm telling, the code I have so far is making me confuse because If I access position 0,0 it will return 1 but that is making me confuse because position 0,0 is position 0 in line which is 1 and position 0 in column wich is 4 that's why I'm confused honestly

Comment: Also, it's pretty simple: `from_matrix = lambda matrix, a, b: matrix[a][b]: `

Comment: Why would you want a function for this? It'd be longer and slower than doing the indexing directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Think of it as a list of lists](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/iteration.html#nested-data) rather than a "matrix", and the logic becomes more obvious. Matrix `m` has two elements: `m[0] = [1, 2, 3]` and `m[1] = [4, 5, 6]`. So accessing a single value from within those lists requires another index. For example, `m[0][1] = 2`.

```
def matrix(m, a, b):
    return m[a][b] # element b from list a in list m
```

If you really want to use a *matrix*, [consider numpy.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6667361/2118067)

Comment: Thank you Erica, basicly two lines of code to solve a problem so simple that seemed complicated in my head. Thanks you once more