# Python and Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I'm relatively new to python so this has me scratching my head, probably because there's some concept that I have completely wrong about how this works in python.

Basically, my goal is to have a multi-dimensional array/list that will consist of 3 elements - a day number, an interval number and a dictionary of data points. Within each day, there are 48 intervals, and each interval will have a single dictionary of data.

What I'm having problems with is building the array the way that I want, but I cannot figure out how to make this work.

Here is the relevant code. How would I assign the data to the array in the format I detailed above? Everything I try gives me an assignment error. Thanks appreciate any help!

```
def get_intraday_data(start_date):
for day in range(0, 7):
    if day == 0:
        num_rows = 49
    else:
        num_rows = 48
    for row in range(0, num_rows):
        if day == 0 and row <= settings.skip_row:
            interval = row
        elif day == 0 and row > settings.skip_row:
            interval = row - 1
        elif day != 0:
            interval = row
        if day == 0 and row == settings.skip_row:
            pass
        else:
            daily_data['date'] = get_date(start_date, day)
            daily_data['interval'] = get_interval(day, row, interval)
            daily_data['forecast_calls'] = (
                get_forecast_calls(day, row, interval))
            daily_data['forecast_aht'] = get_aht(day, row, interval)
            daily_data['forecast_required'] = (
                get_forecast_required(day, row, interval))
            daily_data['calc_required'] = (
            calc_required(daily_data['forecast_required'], 
            daily_data['forecast_aht']))
            daily_data['sched_open'] = (
                get_sched_open(day, row, interval))
```

edit: I previously read the question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201), but that is for a two-dimensional list, not three...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python

Comment: Why you use `pass`  there?

Comment: I don't want it to do anything there. Basically, in the excel sheet I'm working with, there's a single row that is there which needs to be ignored.

Comment: Use `continue` instead