# Which data structure in Python to use to replace Excel 2-dim array of strings/amounts?

Tags: python, arrays, vba, excel, xlwings

I am using xlwings to replace my VB code with Python but since I am not an experienced programmer I was wondering - which data structure to use?

1. Data is in .xls in 2 columns and has the following form; In VB I lift this into a basic two dimensional array *arrCampaignsAmounts(i, j)*:

   > Col 1: '**market_channel_campaign_product**'; Col 2: '**2334.43** $'
2. Then I concatenate words from 4 columns on another sheet into a similar 'string', into another 2-dim array *arrStrings(i, j)*:

   > '**Austria_Facebook_Winter_Active vacation**'; '**rowNumber**'
3. Finally, I search strings from 1. array within strings from 2. array; if found I write amounts into rowNumber from *arrStrings(i, 2)*.

Would I use 4 lists for this task?
Two dictionaries?
Something else?

Comment: You should take a look at `pandas` and its `DataFrame` structure. It it basically a large array with columns name and row index.

Comment: HarryPotfleur - I'm currently playing around with Pythons default csv impot (reader). I can get it to import data and print to terminal, do you know what data structure does it import to? Strings, List? Will check out Pandas

Comment: I think pandas as a method to import/export to/from csv file

Comment: The standard library documentation for Python is pretty good. For the CSV reader look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html Basically csv.reader returns a reader object that allows you to iterate over each line and each line gets converted to a list.

Comment: This might help: [How to define two-dimensional array in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use pandas Dataframes.  Here are references and very simple Dataframe examples.

```
#reference: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html 
#reference: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def df_dupes(df_in):
    '''
    Returns [object,count] pairs for each unique item in the dataframe.    
    '''
    # import pandas
    if isinstance(df_in, list) or isinstance(df_in, tuple):
        import pandas as pd
        df_in = pd.DataFrame(df_in)
    return df_in.groupby(df_in.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size()


def df_filter_example(df):
    '''
    In [96]: df
    Out[96]:
       A  B  C  D
    0  1  4  9  1
    1  4  5  0  2
    2  5  5  1  0
    3  1  3  9  6
    '''
    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.DataFrame([[1,4,9,1],[4,5,0,2],[5,5,1,0],[1,3,9,6]],columns=['A','B','C','D'])
    return df[(df.A == 1) & (df.D == 6)]

def df_compare(df1, df2, compare_col_list, join_type):
    '''
    df_compare compares 2 dataframes.
    Returns left, right, inner or outer join
    df1 is the first/left dataframe
    df2 is the second/right dataframe
    compare_col_list is a lsit of column names that must match between df1 and df2
    join_type = 'inner', 'left', 'right' or 'outer'
    '''              
    import pandas as pd
    return pd.merge(df1, df2, how=join_type,
                on=compare_col_list)

def df_compare_examples():
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
    '''        c1  c2  c3
            0   1   2   3
            1   4   5   6
            2   7   8   9   '''
    df2=pd.DataFrame([[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]], columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
    '''        c1  c2  c3
            0   4   5   6
            1   7   8   9
            2  10  11  12   '''
    # One can see that df1 contains 1 row ([1,2,3]) not in df3 and 
    # df2 contains 1 rown([10,11,12])  not in df1.

    # Assume c1 is not relevant to the comparison.  So, we merge on cols 2 and 3.
    df_merge = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',on=['c2','c3'])
    print(df_merge)
    '''        c1_x  c2  c3  c1_y
            0     1   2   3   NaN
            1     4   5   6     4
            2     7   8   9     7
            3   NaN  11  12    10   '''
    ''' One can see that columns c2 and c3 are returned.  We also received
            columns c1_x and c1_y, where c1_X is the value of column c1
            in the first dataframe and c1_y is the value of c1 in the second
            dataframe.  As such, 
               any row that contains c1_y = NaN is a row from df1 not in df2 &  
               any row that contains c1_x = NaN is a row from df2 not in df1. ''' 
    df1_unique = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',on=['c2','c3'])
    df1_unique = df1_unique[df1_unique['c1_y'].isnull()]
    print(df1_unique)
    df2_unique = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='right',on=['c2','c3'])
    print(df2_unique)
    df_common =  pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner',on=['c2','c3'])
    print(df_common)


def delete_column_example():
    print 'create df'
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['a','b','c'])
    print 'drop (delete/remove) column'
    col_name = 'b'
    df.drop(col_name, axis=1, inplace=True)  # or  df = df.drop('col_name, 1)

def delete_rows_example():
    print '\n\ncreate df'
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['col_1','col_2','col_3'])
    print(df)
    print '\n\nappend rows'
    df= df.append(pd.DataFrame([[11,22,33]], columns=['col_1','col_2','col_3']))
    print(df)
    print '\n\ndelete rows where (based on) column value'
    df = df[df.col_1 == 4]
    print(df)
```