# How to create the matrix AxB in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create this matrix AxB with a specific pattern in Python :

```
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
[0.0, -1.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
[0.0, 0.0, -1.0]
```

The problem is that I want to create this matrix without having to resort to hard coding it. Can someone help me to isolate the pattern, and fill the matrix dynamically?

Here is what I've tried so far :

```
matrix_test = [[0.0 for i in range(3)] for i in range(6)]
for x in range(3):
    matrix_test [x][x] = 1.0
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python

Comment: So, you need `2 x A^2`?

Comment: I need the 2 first rows is

[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0],

And the next is

[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
[0.0, -1.0, 0.0],

and next ...

Comment: This is not a duplicate. What OP wants is not just how to make a list-of-lists to represent a matrix, but a matrix with a certain pattern in it.

Comment: @HienBui: the question was closed but here you go: https://gist.github.com/drdaeman/f88ce23a013389e0118f86e91a44f97c

Comment: @drdaeman: thank you so much for your helping and your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matrix_test = [[0.0 for i in range(3)] for i in range(6)]
for x in range(3):
    matrix_test [2 * x][x] = 1.0
    matrix_test [2 * x + 1][x] = -1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I think this solution doesn't correct. I have tried with this also and get the result: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, -1.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, -1.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

Comment: Use `2*x` and `2*x+1` for the first index instead of `x` and `x+1`.

Comment: thanks for the hint, @Hien Bui try again

Comment: Thank you Nils Werner and xnx for your helping.