# Why does filling in one row in Python fill the entire array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

Here is my code:

```
arr = [[0]*5]*6

print arr

for i in xrange(5):
    arr[0][i] = 'T'

print arr
```

Here is the output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T']]
```

Why is this happening? I guess I'm more familiar with Java where iterating through arr[0][i] would only fill the top row of the array. And it makes no sense to me that it's different in Python since printing arr[i][j] (for some valid i, j) does in fact print the one item I expect at arr[i][j].

EDIT: In my defense about this being a duplicate, the question indicated as a duplicate of this one (and the question marked as a duplicate of *that* question) did not appear in my search whatsoever. Clearly I was typing in the wrong words to describe this phenomenon since I didn't know what it was called.

Comment: You're not filling a multidimensional array, you're filling an array of arrays. All those arrays happen to be the *same* array. There are just 6 of them.

Comment: This is the same behaviour in Java too, except that in Java one frequently uses multidimensional arrays instead of arrays of arrays.

Comment: Oh weird. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python, which is I guess how I was supposed to do it. THANK YOU!!!