# Trying to construct identity matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, matrix

Write a function identity(n) that returns the n identity
 matrix.
For example: identity(3) outputs [[1,0,0][0,1,0][0,0,1]]
I have tried as follow:

```
def identity(n):
matrix=[[0]*n]*n
i=0
while i<n:
    matrix[i][i]=1
    i+=1
return matrix
```

Also I tried with range but it did'n work like this

```
def identity(n):
    matrix=[[0]*n]*n
    k=matrix[:]
    i=0
    for i in range(1,n):
        matrix[i][i]=1
        i+=1
    return k
print(identity(5))
```

But it output for `n = 5`:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If numpy is not allowed ... Know this [How to define two-dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

and do this

```
def identity(n):
    m=[[0 for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]
    for i in range(0,n):
        m[i][i] = 1
    return m
```

Comment: Oneliner: `identity = [[0]*i + [1] + [0]*(n-i-1) for i in range(n) ]`

Comment: Way too late but I kept thinking this was too long and came up with:

`m=[[int(x==y) for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]`

Answer (score 4):

This is because the way you are initializing `matrix`.  Each sublist of  `[[0]*n]*n` is **the same list `[0]*n`**, or in other words, each row of your matrix is a *reference* to the same underlying row.  You can verify this using `id`:

```
> x = [[0]*3]*3
> x
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
> id(x[0])
140017690403112
> id(x[1])
140017690403112
> id(x[2])
140017690403112
```

TTherefore, when you assign a value to the `i`th row of your matrix, you're assigning it to all rows.  So avoid nested list creation using `[0]*n`.  Instead, use

```
matrix = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)]
```

Even simpler, avoid all of this with:

```
import numpy as np
np.eye(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Numpy has this built in, you can just use np.eye(n):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.eye(4)

In [3]: x
Out[3]:
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```