# Issues using Regex on href with a tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to extract text from a tag based on `href` containing a certain string, below is part of my sample code:

```
Experience = soup.find_all(id='background-experience-container')

Exp = {}

for element in Experience:
    Exp['Experience'] = {}


for element in Experience:
    role = element.find(href=re.compile("title").get_text()
    Exp['Experience']["Role"] = role


for element in Experience:
    company = element.find(href=re.compile("exp-company-name").get_text()
    Exp['Experience']['Company'] = company
```

It doesn't like the syntax for how I've defined the `Exp['outer_key']['inner_key'] = value` it is returning `SyntaxError`.

I'm trying to buld a `Dict.dict` which contains info on role and company, will also look to include dates for each but haven't got that far yet.

Can anyone spot any glaringly obvious mistakes in my code?

Really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define two-dimensional array in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Comment: It seems like `Exp['Experience']["Role"] = role` does not work because it's essentially uninitialized. From the other ticket, it seems that you may use `.append(...)` instead or initialize the array beforehand.

Comment: @Lupinity mine is a slightly different ask - I want to build an output like the following: {Experience : {role: role_name, company: company_name}, {role: role_name, company: company_name},....}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_all` can return many values (even if you search by `id`) so better use `list` to keep all values - `Exp = []`.

```
Experience = soup.find_all(id='background-experience-container')

# create empty list
Exp = []

for element in Experience:
    # create empty dictionary
    dic = {}

    # add elements to dictionary
    dic['Role'] = element.find(href=re.compile("title")).get_text()
    dic['Company'] = element.find(href=re.compile("exp-company-name")).get_text()

    # add dictionary to list
    Exp.append(dic)

# display

print(Exp[0]['Role'])
print(Exp[0]['Company'])

print(Exp[1]['Role'])
print(Exp[1]['Company'])

# or

for x in Exp:
    print(x['Role'])
    print(x['Company'])
```

if you sure that `find_all` gives you only one element (and you need key `'Experience'`) then you can do

```
Experience = soup.find_all(id='background-experience-container')

# create main dictionary
Exp = {}

for element in Experience:
    # create empty dictionary
    dic = {}

    # add elements to dictionary
    dic['Role'] = element.find(href=re.compile("title")).get_text()
    dic['Company'] = element.find(href=re.compile("exp-company-name")).get_text()

    # add dictionary to main dictionary
    Exp['Experience'] = dic

# display

print(Exp['Experience']['Role'])
print(Exp['Experience']['Company'])
```

or

```
Experience = soup.find_all(id='background-experience-container')

# create main dictionary
Exp = {}

for element in Experience:
    Exp['Experience'] = {
       'Role': element.find(href=re.compile("title")).get_text()
       'Company': element.find(href=re.compile("exp-company-name")).get_text()
    }

# display

print(Exp['Experience']['Role'])
print(Exp['Experience']['Company'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried amending my code using your first resolution however I'm getting an error 
    dic['Company'] = element.find(href=re.compile("exp-company   name").get_text()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I forgot `)` before `.get_text()` - ie. `element.find(href=re.compile("exp-company-name")).get_text()`