# Matrix manipulation in python

Tags: python, matrix

I'm a beginner to coding and have been trying to operate on matrices for a bit, but got stuck at a point. 
I've got a 224x224 matrix of integers and need to apply a function over 8x8 patches of the matrix, individually. (28 patches, each 8x8)
How do I do this?

Comment: So you think this looks the same for all kinds of matrix-implementions? There is no native matrix in python.

Comment: It's an integer matrix. Edited. Thanks for reminding

Comment: That is the least of parameters that matter. Just calculate your stride-size and do a nested for-loop. For optimized implementations, checkout skimage's ```view_as_blocks``` (numpy-array based).

Comment: What do you mean by "matrix". Again *there is no native matrix in Python*. So what, exactly, are you referring to as a "matrix?" A list-of-lists? Some kind of `numpy` array?

Comment: Is it a [matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python) as the one defined in that answer, a nested list, a dictionary or a numpy array? Matrix is not in native python. Please clarify your question.

Comment: You'll have to post some code. If you're using `numpy`, your matrices might look one way. If you're using pure python, you might mean `matrix[i][j]`. They are different, and the answers you get will be different, because of that.

Comment: Also, did you mean 784 patches, each 8x8? Because 224x224 / 8x8 = 28x28.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
# Just make up a 224x224 matrix
Matrix = [ [row*col for col in range(224)] for row in range(224)]

def f(m, r, c):
    for row in range(r, r+8):
        for col in range(c, c+8):
            m[row][col] += 1    # whatever operation goes here

def apply_func_to_matrix_by_8(m, f):
    nr = len(m)
    nc = len(m[0])

    for row in range(0, nr, 8):
        for col in range(0, nc, 8):
            f(m, row, col)


apply_func_to_matrix_by_8(Matrix, f)
```