# Index Out Of Range When Artificially Limited

Tags: python, list

when I run this program, sometimes I receive an error.This error however is not possible as I am using an 8x8 grid and I limit the inputs so that they can only be numbers from 0-7, to obey the fact that list indexes start at 0.

The user must input coordinates (1-8),(A-H) and the program will check to see if those coordinates are correct, by systematically going through the CompShips list and repeatedly comparing those coordinates to ones given by the user. If the cords match, then a message will appear and a "Z" will change to an "X" on those coordinates, indicating a HIT. If the guess does not match, a "Z" will change to an "M" on those coordinates indicating a MISS.

```
CompShips=[[1,0],[1,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[3,0],[3,1],[3,2],[5,4],[5,5],[5,6],[5,7],[1,7],[2,7],[3,7],[4,7],[5,7]] 
FRow1=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow2=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow3=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow4=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow5=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow6=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow7=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow8=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
def PrintFireBoard():
    print(Index)
    print(FRow1)
    print(FRow2)
    print(FRow3)
    print(FRow4)
    print(FRow5)
    print(FRow6)
    print(FRow7)
    print(FRow8)
FireBoard=[FRow1,FRow2,FRow3,FRow4,FRow5,FRow6,FRow7,FRow8]
while len(CompShips) !=0 or CompSuccess==17:
    FireRow=input("Please Choose The Row That You Wish To Fire Upon (1-8) ")
    FireIndex=input("Please Choose The Column That You Wish To Fire Upon (A-H) ")
    #As Lists start at 0
    FireRow=int(FireRow)-1
    if FireIndex==("A"):
        FireIndex=0
    elif FireIndex==("B"):
        FireIndex=1
    elif FireIndex==("C"):
        FireIndex=2
    elif FireIndex==("D"):
         FireIndex=3
    elif FireIndex==("E"):
        FireIndex=4
    elif FireIndex==("F"):
        FireIndex=5
    elif FireIndex==("G"):
        FireIndex=6
    elif FireIndex==("H"):
        FireIndex=7
Guess=[FireRow,FireIndex]
#Check To See If Correct
UserSuccess=0
for i in CompShips:
    if Guess==i:
        CompShips.remove(Guess)
        UserSuccess=1
    else:
        pass
if UserSuccess==1:
    print("HIT")
    print(FireRow)
    print(FireIndex)
    FireBoard[[FireRow][FireIndex]]=("H")
    PrintFireBoard()
else:
    print("MISS")
    print(FireRow)
    print(FireIndex)
    FireBoard[[FireRow][FireIndex]]=("M")
    PrintFireBoard()
```

I receive the error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Does it tell you on which line `IndexError` occurred?

Comment: Just a small comment, instead of building the board like that, you can use this nifty trick to expand items into a list.
`["Z"] * 8` will produce `['Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z']` so 
`[["Z"]*8]*8` will produce an 8x8 list of list with "Z" as the elements.

Comment: @AxelPersinger That will create 8 copies of the outer array, so if you modify one, they're all changed. You need to do this: `[['Z' for i in range(8)] for j in range(8)]`

Comment: @user3080953, that's correct, I totally forgot about that! Your answer is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @AxelPersinger: `["Z"]*8` is ok because strings are immutable, and any operation on them actually replaces the object; but `[["Z"]*8]*8` is a big no - you are going to get a list containing 8 references to the same sublist, so if you do - say `FireBoard[0][0]="A"` you'll get an `A` in the first column of each row - because all rows refer to the same list. The correct way to go is `[["Z"]*8 for _ in range(8)]`.

Comment: Uh I was preceded.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like these two lines

```
FireBoard[[FireRow][FireIndex]]=("H")
FireBoard[[FireRow][FireIndex]]=("M")
```

should be

```
FireBoard[FireRow][FireIndex]="H"
FireBoard[FireRow][FireIndex]="M"
```

---

**Explanation:** In your old code, `FireBoard[[FireRow][FireIndex]]=("H")`

`[FireRow][FireIndex]` means, given a list `[FireRow]` (which contains just one element), get the `FireIndex`-th element. This is not what you're trying to do.

For example `[3][0]` returns `3`, and `[3][1]` gives `IndexError`.

Take a look at [How to define a two-dimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Also note that `("H")` is the same as the string `"H"`. There is no need to add parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation in your question was off. I think that all the code from

```
 Guess=[FireRow,FireIndex]
```

until the end should be preceded by 4 spaces.

I've removed print(Index) since it was not defined.

To access FireBoard use:

```
FireBoard[FireRow][FireIndex]
```

Instead of

```
FireBoard[[FireRow][FireIndex]]
```

This should be working

```
CompShips=[[1,0],[1,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[3,0],[3,1],[3,2],[5,4],

[5,5],[5,6],[5,7],[1,7],[2,7],[3,7],[4,7],[5,7]] 
FRow1=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow2=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow3=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow4=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow5=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow6=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow7=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
FRow8=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
def PrintFireBoard():
    print(FRow1)
    print(FRow2)
    print(FRow3)
    print(FRow4)
    print(FRow5)
    print(FRow6)
    print(FRow7)
    print(FRow8)
FireBoard=[FRow1,FRow2,FRow3,FRow4,FRow5,FRow6,FRow7,FRow8]
while len(CompShips) !=0 or CompSuccess==17:
    FireRow=input("Please Choose The Row That You Wish To Fire Upon (1-8) ")
    FireIndex=input("Please Choose The Column That You Wish To Fire Upon (A-H) ")
    #As Lists start at 0
    FireRow=int(FireRow)-1
    if FireIndex==("A"):
        FireIndex=0
    elif FireIndex==("B"):
        FireIndex=1
    elif FireIndex==("C"):
        FireIndex=2
    elif FireIndex==("D"):
         FireIndex=3
    elif FireIndex==("E"):
        FireIndex=4
    elif FireIndex==("F"):
        FireIndex=5
    elif FireIndex==("G"):
        FireIndex=6
    elif FireIndex==("H"):
        FireIndex=7
    Guess=[FireRow,FireIndex]
    #Check To See If Correct
    UserSuccess=0
    for i in CompShips:
        if Guess==i:
            CompShips.remove(Guess)
            UserSuccess=1
        else:
            pass
    if UserSuccess==1:
        print("HIT")
        print(FireRow)
        print(FireIndex)
        FireBoard[FireRow][FireIndex]=("H")
        PrintFireBoard()
    else:
        print("MISS")
        print(FireRow)
        print(FireIndex)
        FireBoard[FireRow][FireIndex]=("M")
        PrintFireBoard()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a  much cleaner code!

```
CompShips=[[1,0],[1,1],[2,2],[2,3],
           [2,4],[3,0],[3,1],[3,2],
           [5,4],[5,5],[5,6],[5,7],
           [1,7],[2,7],[3,7],[4,7],
           [5,7]] 

FRow=[["Z"]*8]*8   #1 More Pythonic


def PrintFireBoard():
    #print(Index)
    for i in range(0,8):
        print(FRow[i])

FireBoard=FRow[:]  #NOTE THIS ONE!!!

mydict = {}
for i,key in enumerate(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]): #2 More Pythonic
    mydict[key] = i


while len(CompShips) !=0 or CompSuccess==17:
    FireRow=input("Please Choose The Row That You Wish To Fire Upon (1-8) ")
    FireIndex=input("Please Choose The Column That You Wish To Fire Upon (A-H) ")

    FireRow=int(FireRow)-1
    FireIndex = mydict[FireIndex]
    Guess=[FireRow,FireIndex]
    print(Guess)

    UserSuccess=0
    for i in CompShips:
        if Guess==i:
            CompShips.remove(Guess)
            UserSuccess=1
        else:
            pass
    if UserSuccess==1:
        print("HIT")
        print(FireRow,FireIndex)
        FireBoard[FireRow][FireIndex]="H" #3 your problem here
        PrintFireBoard()
    else:
        print("MISS")
        print(FireRow,FireIndex)
        FireBoard[FireRow][FireIndex]="M"
        PrintFireBoard()
```

1) As explained in the comments that's just a more nicer way to create a list of lists!. Remember **DRY** principle! *Do Not Repeat* yourself!

2) Instead of having all that if else to convert the 'A' to 0. You can use a dictionary lookup instead!

3) Your problem seems to be here! correct this to  `FireBoard[FireRow][FireIndex]="H"`

PS: *NOTE THIS ONE!!!*: I'm not just making **FireBoard** as an alias to **FRow**! I'm copying it into a FireBoard as a new list! There's a [subtle difference](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/) read about it here. I'm doing this incase you don't want your original  FRow list to be modified!