# How can I do a matrix of unknown number of data in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I would like to read a data from file to double nested lists. How can I do it in Python 3? I know that if I know the dimensions beforehand, I can write

```
# Creates a list containing 5 lists, each of 8 items, all set to 0
w, h = 8, 5;
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
```

like in [How to define a two-dimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python) . But in my situation I read data from file and I don't know beforehand how much data there is. So the idea is to increase the matrix size while reading, like
first

```
1 2 3
```

then

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

then

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just `append` to your list of `rows`:

```
Matrix = []
for row in rows:
    Matrix.append(row)
```

that way the matrix just grows.

you could use it like this:

```
from io import StringIO

matrix1_txt='''1 2 3
'''

matrix2_txt='''1 2 3
4 5 6
'''

matrix3_txt='''1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
'''


Matrix = []
with StringIO(matrix3_txt) as file:
    for line in file:
        Matrix.append([int(i) for i in line.split()])

print(Matrix)  # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

(where you'd need to replace `StringIO(matrix3_txt)` by `open('file.txt', 'r)` if your data is in a text file called `file.txt`)