# I want to know how to declare a two dimensional list in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I need a data structure in python that can handle data like this in C:

```
typedef struct lp {
    char pvid[16];
    int ppnum;
} lp_t;

lp_t lpList[100000][3];
```

Basically, I read in a line, process it, and stuff it to an array lpList[lp#][copy#] for the particular physical partition on a disk. Can you help?

Comment: Merely add a list to a list, try it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a two-dimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can define your array as below:

```
array = []

width = 2
height = 2
array = []
for i in range(height):
    row=[]
    for j in range(width):
        row.append(0)
    array.append(row)
```

In the example above, you will have an array of 2 by 2 initialise with zeros.
If you want to change a value, you can just do:

```
array[1][1] = 10
```