# can i call upon a variable via there row in python?

Tags: python, list, variables, python-3.6

Trying to make a simple map for my player and the map uses multiple rows but is there a way i can store all of these rows to 1 variable? so i can print them all at once at also i can call upon them like print(row[2][4])

```
row1 = [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"]
row2 = [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"]
row3 = [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"]
row4 = [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"]
row5 = [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"]
row6 = [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"]
row7 = [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"]
```

i understand i could condense this to a function and print it at once but i want to call upon it as stated above

Comment: [How to define a two-dimensional array in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/6667201)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a two-dimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; in Python one can make a list of lists, which would accomplish what you wish. You could either use your existing variables and set rows thus:

```
rows = [row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7]
```

or you could simply dispense with the individual rows and set the 2D list in one go, thus:

```
row1 = [[" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
        [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
        [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
        [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
        [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
        [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
        [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"]]
```

Then you can access individual elements as you wished, using `rows[2][4]`, and the like.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your existing variables you can do the following:

```
row = [row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7]
print(row[2][4])
```

Or you can define `row` as a list of lists:

```
row = [
    [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
    [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
    [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
    [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
    [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
    [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
    [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
]
print(row[2][4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary:

```
row =   {1 : [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
         2 : [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
         3 : [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
         4 : [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
         5 : [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
         6 : [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"],
         7 : [" -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -", " -"]}
```

This will help you maintain the counting as you had with your variables.

If you already have those variables, same solution could be achieved with `enumerate`:

```
row = dict(enumerate([row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7], 1))
```

You get the same, only in one line.

Comment: Why not a list of list? Do you really that starting at 1 instead of 0 is worth the overhead of a dict against a list?

Comment: @SergeBallesta OP seems to wan't to call it with `1` indexed and this does the job.

Comment: I commented without reading the other answers. This can be an acceptable alternative even if I do not really like it (opinions...). But IMHO you should explain the reason for using a dict. Only one text line is often short for a good answer...