# Arrays - random chance

Tags: python-3.x, grid

I am a beginner at python and I am attempting to create a simple game. I am struggling to create a function that is required to take in zero arguments and returns a grid which contains randomly placed explosives.

As a general requirement, there should be a ten percent chance of getting a mine.

This is my code so far, but I'm struggling to figure out where to go from here. I also don't really understand the ten percent chance of placing a mine requirement because I thought there would have to be 10 different boxes? If someone could help push me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

```
def mines():
    gridSize = 3
    createGrid = [[' ' for i in range(gridSize)] for i in range(gridSize)]
    return createGrid
print(initMines())
```

All of these answers were really helpful, thanks! :)

Comment: If it is only a 3x3 there is a good chance that there will be no mines at a 1 in 10 chance. Are you sure you don't want to define a minimum number of mines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the random library, you can use randint to get your 1 in 10 chance, and implement via an if statement

```
import random

GRIDSIZE = 3
CHANCE = 10

def mines():
    createGrid = [[("x" if random.randint(0, CHANCE) == 0  else  " ") for i in range(GRIDSIZE)] for i in range(GRIDSIZE)]
    return createGrid
print(mines())
```

Output example

```
[['x', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

Edit: I have added global constants for the grid size and chance based on your question, however I would pass these as parameters if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

For a `1/10` chance of a mine, you can just use something like (remembering to `import random`):

```
opts = "M........."
[[random.choice(opts) for c in range(gridSize)] for r in range(gridSize)]
```

It just chooses one of the characters from the string, which happens to have a 10% chance of getting a mine.

Using that in a complete program, and making it more configurable:

```
import random

def mines(gsz, pct):
    # Silently enforce int 0-100, create choices, then choose.

    pct = max(0, min(100, int(pct)))
    opts = "M" * pct + ' ' * (100 - pct)
    return [[random.choice(opts) for i in range(gsz)] for i in range(gsz)]

# Test harness. First, create a grid.

sz = 10
grid = mines(sz, 20)

# Then dump it for confirmation.

for line in grid: print(line)
mineCount = sum([cell == 'M' for row in grid for cell in row])
print('\nActual percentage was', 100 * mineCount / sz / sz)
```

shows it in action:

```
[' ', ' ', 'M', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'M', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['M', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'M', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['M', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'M', 'M', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', 'M', 'M', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['M', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'M', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['M', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'M', 'M', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', 'M', ' ', 'M', ' ', 'M', ' ', ' ', 'M']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'M', ' ', ' ', ' ']

Actual percentage was 19.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not most familiar with Python, so sorry if things don't quite work, but from the looks of things you're looking at making a 2d array, and then filling them with either an empty string "" or a mine "x", based on probability.

Based on the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python), you're mostly on the right track with initialising the array, though you may have to make the two "i"s different (given they represent "coordinates" in an array I'd suggest x and y)

```
createGrid = [[' ' for x in range(gridSize)] for y in range(gridSize)]
```

You then need to populate the array, and the way I'd suggest you do this would be using nested for loops as shown below:

```
for i in range(gridSize)
    for j in range(gridSize)
        createGrid[i][j] = //code for mine/empty
```

This will loop through all values in the array, and then update them based on whether or not it should contain a mine or be empty.

To decide whether or not it should be a mine, your best bet would probably be to import the [random module](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/random/how-to-use-the-random-module-in-python), and use either the randint function or the random function, and then use an if statement to determine whether or not it should be a mine.
(The if statement goes within the for loops, the import happens before anything else in your code)

e.g.

```
import random

if random.randint(0, 10) <= 1
    createGrid[i][j] = "x"
```

Hope that makes sense and is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want guaranteed number of mines you could do this:

```
import random

def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]


size = int(input('Enter length of row: '))

# By default 1/size of cells will be mines.
mines = (size**2)//size

# There is probably a better way to get user input, but this will do.
try:
    mines = int(input('Enter number of mines [default=%s]: ' % mines))
except:
    mines = (size**2)//size

# Make an one dimensional list of size square.
field_1d = [' ']*(size**2)

# Stick the mines into the list.
for m in range(mines):
    field_1d[m] = '*'

# Randomly place the mines.
random.shuffle(field_1d)

# Make a 2D list out of the 1D list.
field = [r for r in chunks(field_1d,size)]

# Display it.
for row in field:
    print(row)
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./minesweeper.py
Enter length of row: 3
Enter number of mines [default=3]: 1
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', '*', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
$ ./minesweeper.py
Enter length of row: 10
Enter number of mines [default=10]:
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' ']
[' ', '*', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*']
[' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

Sorry I could resist.  I went ahead and wrote a complete minesweeper game:

```
import random

class Cell():

    def __init__(self,i,j,field):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.exposed = False
        self.field = field
        self.value = self.calc_value()

    def display(self):
        if self.exposed:
            return self.value
        return '_'

    def expose(self):
        self.exposed = True

    def calc_value(self):
        i = self.i
        j = self.j
        f = self.field

        if self.field[i][j] == '*':
            return '*'
        v=0
        try:
            if f[i-1][j-1] == '*':
                v += 1
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if f[i-1][j] == '*':
                v += 1
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if f[i-1][j+1] == '*':
                v += 1
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if f[i][j-1] == '*':
                v += 1
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if f[i][j+1] == '*':
                v += 1
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if f[i+1][j-1] == '*':
                v += 1
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if f[i+1][j] == '*':
                v += 1
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if f[i+1][j+1] == '*':
                v += 1
        except:
            pass
        return str(v)


def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]


size = int(input('Enter size of field: '))

# 1/10th of cells will be mines.
mines = (size**2)//size

try:
    mines = int(input('Enter number of mines [default=%s]: ' % mines))
except:
    mines = (size**2)//size

# Make an one dimensional list of size square.
field_1d = [' ']*(size**2)

# Stick the mines into the list.
for m in range(mines):
    field_1d[m] = '*'

# Randomly place the mines.
random.shuffle(field_1d)

# Make a 2D list out of the 1D list.
field = [r for r in chunks(field_1d,size)]

# Display it.
for row in field:
    print(row)

board_1d = []
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        print(i,j)
        board_1d.append(Cell(i,j,field))

board = [r for r in chunks(board_1d,size)]
def display(board):
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            print(board[i][j].display(), end='|')
        print("")

def win(board):
    unexposed = 0
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            if board[i][j].exposed == False:
                unexposed += 1

    if unexposed == mines:
        print('WINNER!!!!')
        return True

    return False

gameover = False

while not gameover:
    display(board)
    I = int(input('Enter I: '))
    J = int(input('Enter J: '))
    c = board[I][J]
    c.expose()
    if c.value == '*':
       print("BOOM!")
       gameover = True
    gameover = win(board)

display(board)
```