# python netCDF4 variable multiplication of different dimension

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, netcdf4

I have first variable **h** having dimension **(111,141)** another variable **cs_w** having dimension **(51,)**. Basically my data is ROMS history output data. Now I want to multiply h with cs_w and the final result should be of dimension **(51,111,141)**. Here I got stuck and unabble to proceed. below is my code

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import netCDF4 as nc

f_in = nc.Dataset('ocean_his_0010.nc', "r")



h = f_in.variables['h']

cs_w = f_in.variables['Cs_w']


z=[[],[],[]]
for i in range(len(h[0])):
    for j in range(len(h[1])):
        for k in range(len(cs_w)):
            z[i][j][k] = h[i][j]*cs_w[k]
```

Here is the description of the two variable which I want to use.

> Out[88]: 
>   
>   float64 Cs_w(s_w)
>       long_name: S-coordinate stretching curves at W-points
>       valid_min: -1.0
>       valid_max: 0.0
>       field: Cs_w, scalar
>   unlimited dimensions: 
>   current shape = (51,)
>   filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used

h
Out[89]: 

float64 h(eta_rho, xi_rho)
    long_name: bathymetry at RHO-points
    units: meter
    grid: grid
    location: face
    coordinates: lon_rho lat_rho
    field: bath, scalar
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (111, 141)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used

```
Below is the ncdump ocean_his_0010.nc

netcdf ocean_his_0010 {
dimensions:
        xi_rho = 141 ;
        xi_u = 140 ;
        xi_v = 141 ;
        xi_psi = 140 ;
        eta_rho = 111 ;
        eta_u = 111 ;
        eta_v = 110 ;
        eta_psi = 110 ;
        N = 50 ;
        s_rho = 50 ;
        s_w = 51 ;
        tracer = 2 ;
        boundary = 4 ;
        ocean_time = UNLIMITED ; // (360 currently)

        double Cs_w(s_w) ;
                Cs_w:long_name = "S-coordinate stretching curves at W-points" ;
                Cs_w:valid_min = -1. ;
                Cs_w:valid_max = 0. ;
                Cs_w:field = "Cs_w, scalar" ;
        double h(eta_rho, xi_rho) ;
                h:long_name = "bathymetry at RHO-points" ;
                h:units = "meter" ;
                h:grid = "grid" ;
                h:location = "face" ;
                h:coordinates = "lon_rho lat_rho" ;
                h:field = "bath, scalar" ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just define a (multi-dimensional) list as `z=[[],[],[]]` and start filling it the way you are attempting, it needs to be properly sized first. See e.g. [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python) which deals with the same problem.

Numpy is usually more convenient for dealing with nD-arrays, your `z` array can simply be defined as:

```
z = np.zeros((51,111,141))
```

And be filled using either something like your nested loop, or using [vectorized instructions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html), for example:

```
for k in range(51):
    z[k,:,:] = cs_w[k] * h[:,:]
```

Or even fully automatic (without even having to define `z` beforehand):

```
import numpy as np

h    = np.zeros((111,141))
cs_w = np.zeros(51)

z = cs_w[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis] * h
```

Using these vectorized operations is usually ***a lot*** faster than writing out the loop manually.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The first comment is working properly, but the last I tried whic is giving below error      z = cs_w[:,np.newaxis, np.newaxis]*h
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), and 1-d integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: That's strange, just to be sure I added a full minimal example, can you try that? It runs fine on my system.

Comment: p.s.: I still use the `np.newaxis` approach, but I believe that [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) is now the preferred method.