# 2D array in python changes the whole row when I only want to change 1 item(Is there a way around it?)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.7

I wanted to create a 2D array that would have a number in each cell.
I need to access specific cells and be ablt to change them.

```
def print_matrix(matrix):
    #just to print it nicer
    for x in range(0, len(matrix)):
        print(matrix[x])

matrix = []
list = []
for x in range(0,10):
    list.append(0)

for x in range(0,10):
    matrix.append(list)

matrix[1][2] = 9


print_matrix(matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually created only one list and added it 10 times to the matrix (by reference).

```
matrix = []
for x in range(0,10):
    row = []

    for x in range(0,10):
        row.append(0)

    matrix.append(row)
```

Also, it's not advisable to call variables `list`, for this is a builtin python function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `list.copy()`:

```
def print_matrix(matrix):
    #just to print it nicer
    for x in range(0, len(matrix)):
        print(matrix[x])

matrix = []
list = []
for x in range(0,10):
    list.append(0)

for x in range(0,10):
    matrix.append(list.copy())

matrix[1][2] = 9


print_matrix(matrix)
```

If you don't use copy, `matrix` simply holds 10 references to the original list. Changing any one of those references simply changes the original list.

When you use `.copy()`, new lists are created which are copies of the original one, this allows you to change each one independently.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have `list` references in each row in your matrix. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python) for a possible solution.