# How do I pass in a 1x1 "Cell" object into a 1x1 Block class init method that takes in 3x3 cell objects in a 3x3 list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to python and I'm having trouble passing in a `Cell` object through a `Block` `init` function. I am making a `9x9` grid with 81 cell objects, and every "block" is a `3x3` grid of cells. (like a sudoku board) I am trying to separate the "blocks" in order to analyze whether the block consists of all 1:9 integers. I've successfully made the "grid" (more or less) and now I need to separate the grid into blocks. any help is appreciated!

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self, block_coord =(0,0),block_values = (This should be a 3x3 list of cell objects):            
        self.block_coord = block_coord
        self.block_values = block_values


class Cell:  
    def __init__(self, cell_coord = (0,0), cell_value = 1.0):            
        #stores the coordinate of the cell
        self.cell_coord = cell_coord

        #stores the value of the cell
        self.cell_value = cell_value

    def __call__(self):            
        return Cell(self.cell_coord,self.cell_value)            


    def getCoordinate (self):            
        return self.cell_coord

    def getValue (self):            
        return self.cell_value

    def setValue(self,set_value = 1.0):            
        self.cell_value = set_value

    def setCoordinate(self,set_coordinate = (0,0)):            
        self.cell_coord = set_coordinate
```

Comment: Do you realise that the `get/set` methods in your `Cell` are essentially pointless because you can just edit the properties directly, and they already have defaults. Also you almost certainly don't want that `__call__` method. It creates a copy of the Cell when you call a Cell instance.

Comment: Does the 3x3 list of Cell objects have to increment the coordinates appropriately? Can you edit your post with what you expect this to be.

Comment: Read [how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)