# Something similar to data table of excel in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, datatable

Need help on this.

I have two list, say, `list1 = [2,3,4]` and `list2 = [5,6,7]`. I also have a function that takes two arguments, say, `calc(a,b)`. Now, I want to take arguments form the both of the list. Argument `a` shall be from `list1` and `b` shall from list 2. The result of the calculation should look something like output of data table in excel (for instance `list1` is row variable and `list2` is column variable).

What I have done

```
list1 = [2,3,4]
list2 = [5,6,7]
resultlist = []

def calc(a,b):
    result =  a**2+b
    return result

for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        c = calc(i,j)
        resultlist.append(c)
print(resultlist)
```

The output I got
`[9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23]`

However, I want result to look like

```
      2     3     4
5     9    14    21
6    10    15    22
7    11    16    23
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a two-dimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Build a list for each row and then append that list to your `resultlist`:

```
list1 = [2,3,4]
list2 = [5,6,7]
resultlist = []

def calc(a,b):
    result =  a**2+b
    return result

for i in list1:
    rowlist = []
    for j in list2:
        c = calc(i,j)
        rowlist.append(c)
    resultlist.append(rowlist)
print(resultlist)
```

Elements are easily accessed:

```
# First row
print(resultlist[0])
# Last element of first row
print(resultlist[0][-1])
```

[Try it online](https://repl.it/repls/SunnyAstonishingCoin)

You may want to consider [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) if you're after dataframe like behaviour

Comment: Not exactly how I wanted. In continuation to your suggestion, I transposed the list and got what I was looking for.