# How to create array from input range

Tags: python

- If input is `1` then out is `[ [1] ]`
- If input is `2` then out is `[ [1,2],[3,4] ]`  2x2 array
- if input is `3` then out is `[ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ]`  3x3 array

with respect to number the value will be keep on increasing

```
# A is input
A = 3
matrix = [[0]*A for i in range(A)]
# matrix = []
for i in range(A):
    for j in range(A):
        matrix.append(matrix[i][j])
matrix
```

I tried with below code

```
matrix = [[i+1 for i in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
matrix
```

I am getting `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: Could this help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is almost correct except the line `matrix.append(matrix[i][j])`. Let's dig a bit...

1. Consider the line

   ```
   matrix = [[0]*A for i in range(A)]
   ```

   Here a new matrix of the shape `A x A` is created which is what's expected in the final answer.
2. Then we have the two for loops which are iterating through each row and each column.

   ```
   for i in range(A):      # Iterating through each rows
       for j in range(A):  # Iterating through each columns
           ...
   ```
3. Now, let's look at the erroneous line

   ```
   matrix.append(matrix[i][j])
   ```

   This line adds new values at the end of a perfectly fine matrix which distorts the final shape of the matrix.

What you instead need to do is assign values in the corresponding row and column. Effectively, something like this:

```
matrix[i][j] = ...
```

Now, on the right hand side of the above expression goes `(i * A) + (j + 1)`. So you can rewrite your program as follows:

```
A = 3

# Initialize the matrix
matrix = [[0]*A for i in range(A)]

for i in range(A):
    for j in range(A):
        # Replace the value at the corresponding row and column
        matrix[i][j] = (i * A) + (j + 1)

print(matrix)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

This is a pure Python solution, thus, it does not require any external library.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting n^2 numbers into n bins:

```
np.split(np.arange(n**2)+1, n)
```

In detail:

```
import numpy as np
for n in range(1,4):
    print(np.split(np.arange(n**2)+1, n))
```

Output:

```
[array([1])]
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]
```

Comment: can we do it in python native method

Comment: Sure, please see other answers. This solution is shorter though.

Comment: Additionally, this solution better reads what you actually want: to split n^2 numbers into n bins.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `numpy`, you can use list comprehension:

```py
In [1]: a = 3

In [2]: [[j for j in range(((i-1)*a)+1, (a*i)+1)] for i in range(1, a+1)]
Out[2]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```