# Python matrices without numpy

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to learn how to operate on python matrices but it's difficult since online I'm finding nothing but numpy library and it is forbidden to use it on exams, so, do you have any suggestions on where to find a book, a pdf or a site where I can learn more without using numpy??

Comment: Have you tried using a nested list?

Comment: Yes but i don't know how to move properly so I'm searching examples, even games, like connectfour without using numpy and something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I couldn't use numpy I would use bidimensional lists for matrices.

Example:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

A list that contains list elements that contains numbers.

Numpy is more efficient and if you don't have experience with programming languages like c or c++ some operations could be difficult to implement.

There are a lot of websites to learn with lists, this is a beginner one with clearly and runnable code: https://snakify.org/en/lessons/two_dimensional_lists_arrays/

Comment: If you have more sites link them, I really appreciate

Comment: Another one: [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-2d-arrays-lists-the-right-way/)

And chek this: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array)