# Aliasing when creating an empty grid

Tags: python

If I want to generate a list of 0s of length 5, I can do something like

```
lst = [0] * 5
```

But if I try to extend this to a 5x5 grid by doing

```
grid = [[0] * 5] * 5
```

Something weird seems to happen. I'm not able to change individual cells in the grid. Doing `grid[0][0] = 1`, I would expect this output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Instead, this is what I get:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I'm able to overcome this by using `grid =  [[0] * 5 for _ in range(5)]`, but why does the original method not work? It seems like each row is an alias of each other row. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a two-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-a-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: @AhmedAEK edited for clarity - I'm more so asking why I get this output using this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's define this simple 2x1 list the wrong way.

```py
foo = [[0]]*2
```

this is equivalent to

```py
bar = [0]
foo = [bar, bar]
```

notice that bar is a multable, so any modification to it will modify both foo[0] and foo[1].

```py
bar = [0]
foo = [bar, bar]
bar[0] = 1
print(foo)

#[[1], [1]]
```

while the correct way is equivalent to

```py
foo = []
for i in range(5):
    bar = [0]*5
    foo.append(bar)
```

where each iteration of the loop a new list is created.